# Height of status bar in Android

Tags: android, statusbar

What's the height of the status bar in Android? Is it always the same?

From my measurements it seems that it's 25dp, but I'm not sure if it has the same height on all platforms.

(I want to know this to properly implement a fade transition from an activity that doesn't have status bar to one that does)

Comment: If you do a cross fade then you wont need to know the height of status bar.

Comment: I do need it because some elements are centered in the layout, and I would to have them fade into each other.

Answer (score 397, accepted):

this question was answered before...
[Height of statusbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355367/height-of-statusbar/3356263#3356263)

**Update**::

#### Current method:

ok, the height of the status bar depends on the screen size, for example in a device 
with 240 X 320 screen size the status bar height is 20px, for a device with 320 X 480 screen size the status bar height is 25px, for a device with 480 x 800 the status bar height must be 38px

so i recommend  to use this script to get the status bar height

```
Rect rectangle = new Rect();
Window window = getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
int contentViewTop = 
    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int titleBarHeight= contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;

   Log.i("*** Elenasys :: ", "StatusBar Height= " + statusBarHeight + " , TitleBar Height = " + titleBarHeight);
```

#### (old Method) to get the Height of the status bar on the `onCreate()` method of your Activity, use this method:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() { 
      int result = 0;
      int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      if (resourceId > 0) {
          result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
      } 
      return result;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. I'm also asking if I can assume that the status bar has the same height in all devices.

Comment: Or use dip? If it always has 25dip then the code is not needed.

Comment: you can't assume it's always 25dp (check out the height for example on the kindle fire).

Comment: @ hgpc, nop! you have to get the height value

Comment: does this also work with the action bar  and the system bar as introduced on android API11+ ?

Comment: Re: "the height of the status bar depends on the screen size, for example in a device with 240 X 320 screen size the status bar height is 20px, for a device with 320 X 480 screen size the status bar height is 25px, for a device with 480 x 800 the status bar height must be 38px" - are those just measured pixel values for specific devices having those dimensions? Because since density may vary across devices, those might be the same 25 density-independent pixels times the dpi / 160 (standard density). E.g., a device having a dpi of 240 would have a status bar of 25 * (240/160) = 38

Comment: Doesn't work in runnable passed to view.post() in onCreate() - return 0

Comment: the result is in px ?

Comment: @Paul, yes in in Pixels.

Comment: In a `View.post(new Runnable(){})`, this is resulting in the line `int titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;` computing to `0 = 75 - 75` for me.

Comment: If you want to account for fullscreen implementations in your code, you'll perhaps want to check for the system ui visibility flag: `(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN) == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`

Comment: A device with 720 X 1280 (xhdpi) screen size has the status bar of height 50px.

Comment: isn't the statusbar top above the contenttop???  should be...  int titleBarHeight= statusBarHeight - contentViewTop;  i'm bad at math and all but...

Comment: @me_  left top is the origin, meaning that value of contentViewTop is more than statusBarHeight.

Comment: @Jorgesys I have concerns regarding accuracy of your answer. `contentViewTop` is actually the height of `Toolbar` itself, so no need to subtract anything.
`(@id/content).getTop()` returns the top relative to its parent and only child above the `@id/content` is the `toolbar` (`status bar` is not the child in current parent). Hence the value returned by `window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop()` is in fact the toolbar height.
I've verified this in emulator. Please correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: `window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle)` is not a correct way to get status bar height if you are in multi-window mode + portrait rotation + second window. You will get a huge value (include the 1st height).

Comment: In Multi-Window (Resizeable activity), the new method not works properly. Better one is the old method.

Comment: Updated answer is quite good. The only thing I would change is ```statusBarHeight``` to  ```statusBarTop```

Answer (score 234):

Out of all the code samples I've used to get the height of the status bar, the only one that actually appears to work in the `onCreate` method of an `Activity` is this:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Apparently the actual height of the status bar is kept as an Android resource. The above code can be added to a `ContextWrapper` class (e.g. an `Activity`).

Found at http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/

Comment: Instead of hard coding it, better to calculate dynamically. The above method worked for me!

Comment: shouldn't you use getDimension(...) instead ?

Comment: A word of caution - this does not work on all devices. E.g. on Transformer TF201 (as well as TF101, TF300 and some other devices) the height is reported as 25 where there is no status bar.

Comment: Based on the comments above, it seems to me that the code is telling you what the height of the status bar is on a particular device -- not what it is on a particular activity (which may not actually have a status bar).

Comment: in XML the dimen resource  "@android:dimen/status_bar_height"  can be used. 
     <!-- Height of the status bar  defined in android system source file -->
    <dimen name="status_bar_height">24dp</dimen>. But you can not direct reference it in your app project. So you must used code.

Answer (score 67):

Hardcoding the size or using reflection to get the value of `status_bar_height` is considered bad practice. Chris Banes [talked about this in at the Droidcon New York](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE&t). The recommended way of getting the status bar size is via the [OnApplyWindowInsetsListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener.html):

```
myView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets -> {
  val statusBarSize = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
  return insets
}
```

This was added in API 20 and is also backported via [ViewAppCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View,%20android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener)).

Comment: This is the most accurate answer today

Comment: for me this only fires once, If I have fragments via bottom nav. If I replace the fragment again, this listener doesnt get called, is there a compat getter aswell?

Comment: And yet this API is horrible, because the number of WTF/Gotchas behind the scenes is huge. You’d think that you can do it with any view, but no, you need to override certain things and ensure YOU pass the insets to your children (??) because SOME ViewGroups will (material design) and ALL OTHERS won’t (linear layout? ConstraintLayout? hello?). Instead of the system having a Window.getStatusBarSize()… we have to SUBSCRIBE TO A FREAKING LISTENER… go home Android, you’re drunk. Just hardcode the size until Google wakes up, we’re in 2018. I hope Chris Banes sees this one day…

Comment: In my case it is not getting fired. I put it Activity#onCreated. Did I do something wrong? Additionally why do not we use mView.getRootWindowInsets()?

Comment: You need to call view.onApplyWindowInsets, because otherwise the view's own method won't be called. Moreover, your code is syntactically wrong (misplaced brace, return statement from closure).

Comment: `insets.systemWindowInsetTop` is deprecated now. So the most actual way now how to get statusbar insets today: 
`val statusbarInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())` and then `statusbarInsets.top`. Read more about how to handle overlaps using insets when implementing edge-to-edge https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge#handle-overlaps

Answer (score 51):

On MDPI devices, the status bar is 25px. We can use this as the base and multiply it by the density (rounded up) to get the status bar height on any device:

```
int statusBarHeight = Math.ceil(25 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

For reference: ldpi=.75, mdpi=1, hdpi=1.5, xhdpi=2

Comment: This is correct for devices that *have* a status bar.  Note that since the above was written, it became true that not all devices will have one.  Specifically, devices running ICS may have a combined status/nav bar at the bottom and nothing at all at the top.  So for that case, for most programming purposes, you would want to assign a height of zero to the status bar, but the above formulation would give you a non-zero size.

Comment: Also the 25px value is not correct for all mdpi devices.  It can vary based on API level.  For example, the 10.1 WXGA tablet emulator device reports 25px at API 16 & 19, but 24px at API 24.

Comment: Constant usage (like 25) is not work correctly all time, you may try to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523854/3341089 solution.

Answer (score 40):

I've merged some solutions together:

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight(final Context context) {
    final Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    else
        return (int) Math.ceil((VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M ? 24 : 25) * resources.getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

another alternative:

```
    final View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(view, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int statusBarHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Alternative to runJustBeforeBeingDrawn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136027/878126

Comment: getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels 
-getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getMeasuredHeight() 
not work in android lolipop

Comment: @ArMo372 Updated answer. It's just that the view needs to pass the measurement first. You don't need to use runJustBeforeBeingDrawn if you've passed it already. You will use it only on too-early cases.

Answer (score 34):

According to [Material Guidance](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#status-bar); height of status bar is 24 dp.

If you want get status bar height in pixels you can use below method:

```
private static int statusBarHeight(android.content.res.Resources res) {
    return (int) (24 * res.getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

which can be called from activity with:

```
statusBarHeight(getResources());
```

Comment: Until Marshmallow it was 25dp. Since Marshmallow it's 24dp.

Comment: this is essentially hardcoding the value - which doesn't allow for design changes

Comment: and doesn't account for the fact that the status bar will not be displayed in same cases

Comment: Here's the latest link: https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html#status-bar

Answer (score 25):

The default height used to be 25dp. With Android Marshmallow (API 23) the height was reduced to 24dp.

Update: Please be aware that since the age of notches and punch-whole-cameras began, using a static height for the status bar no longer works. Please use window insets instead!

Comment: sweet! I just made a dimens.xml specifically for API level 23+ where I've hardcoded the height as 24dp.

Answer (score 21):

this also work with the refrence [link](http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/)

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
  int result = 0;
  int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
  if (resourceId > 0) {
      result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Kotlin version that combines two best solutions

```
fun getStatusBarHeight(): Int {
    val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
    return if (resourceId > 0) resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
    else Rect().apply { window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(this) }.top
}
```

1. Takes `status_bar_height` value if present
2. If `status_bar_height` is not present, calculates the status bar height from Window decor

Comment: Is this the correct way to get in status bar height? can you attach the document please.

Comment: Ad 1.: Use of this function is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code.

Answer (score 17):

Official height is `24dp`, 
as is stated officially by Google on [Android Design webpage](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs).

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem of having to get the status bar height in an onCreate. This works for me.

```
private static final int LOW_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = 19;

private static final int MEDIUM_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = 25;

private static final int HIGH_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = 38;
```

Inside the onCreate:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

int statusBarHeight;

switch (displayMetrics.densityDpi) {
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        statusBarHeight = HIGH_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        statusBarHeight = MEDIUM_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        statusBarHeight = LOW_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
        break;
    default:
        statusBarHeight = MEDIUM_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
}
```

See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Comment: I like your idea of using density-driven values.  If you're going to use the code in multiple places (or use other density-related values) I prefer offloading the work to the system, and storing the values in a dimen resource, which makes the switch unnecessary.  You do need to create a dimension-specific folder and resource file for each density. final Resources res = context.getResources();
            int statusbarHeight = 0;
            try {
                statusbarHeight = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.android_statusbar_height);
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {}

Comment: Hardcoding these values is dangerous, what if they change in a later platform version?

Comment: I think that instead of using hardcoded pixels sizes (one for each density), it's better to use "25dp" .

Answer (score 13):

Yes when i try it with View it provides the result of 25px.
Here is the whole code :

```
public class SpinActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout lySpin = new LinearLayout(this);
        lySpin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);       
        lySpin.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
                int statusBarHeight = rect.top;
                int contentViewTop = 
                    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
                int titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;
                System.out.println("TitleBarHeight: " + titleBarHeight 
                    + ", StatusBarHeight: " + statusBarHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code is working for me when i create a new linear layout as you have done above, but when i do findviewbyid for the lySpin from the xml. then it returns null. not understanding y it is behaving so.

Comment: Because the layout doesn't know its size yet in onCreate because it hasn't finished being drawn. What I usually do is post a Runnable on the UI thread from onCreate which gives the UI time to draw itself.

Answer (score 9):

> **240x320 - 20px**
>
> **320x480 - 25px**
>
> **480x800+ - 38px**

Comment: This is no longer accurate. Use a method of measuring the status bar.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    Window win = this.getWindow();
    win.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    int statusBarHeight = rect.top;
    int contentViewTop = win.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
    int titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;
    Log.d("ID-ANDROID-CONTENT", "titleBarHeight = " + titleBarHeight );
```

it didn't work for me in the onCreate method for the activity, but did when I put it in an onClickListener and gave me a measurement of 25

Comment: I suspect that at the point he tested in onCreate(), the status bar had not yet been created.  By contrast, when he manually clicked to activate his onClickListener() code, the bar had already had plenty of think-type time to display, and he was able to retrieve its size.

Answer (score 7):

the height of the status bar is 24dp in android 6.0

```
 <!-- Height of the status bar -->
 <dimen name="status_bar_height">24dp</dimen>
 <!-- Height of the bottom navigation / system bar. -->
 <dimen name="navigation_bar_height">48dp</dimen>
```

you can find the answer in the source code: frameworks\base\core\res\res\values\dimens.xml

Comment: is there a way to get this resource in our XMLs? `@android:dimen/status_bar_height` does not work for me

Answer (score 6):

To solve this, I used a combination approach.
This is necessary as on tablets the system bar already subtracts it's pixels when display.getHeight() is called.
So I first check if a system bar is present, and then Ben Claytons approach, which works fine on phones.

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int statusBarHeight = 0;

    if (!hasOnScreenSystemBar()) {
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
    }

    return statusBarHeight;
}

private boolean hasOnScreenSystemBar() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int rawDisplayHeight = 0;
    try {
        Method getRawHeight = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
        rawDisplayHeight = (Integer) getRawHeight.invoke(display);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    int UIRequestedHeight = display.getHeight();

    return rawDisplayHeight - UIRequestedHeight > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [@Niklas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android/47125610#47125610) +1 this is the correct way to do it.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements android.support.v4.View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener {

    Rect windowInsets;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        View rootview = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        android.support.v4.View.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(rootview, this);
    }

    android.support.v4.View.WindowInsetsCompat android.support.v4.View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener.OnApplyWindowInsets(View v, android.support.v4.View.WindowInsetsCompat insets)
    {
        windowInsets = new Rect();
        windowInsets.set(insets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft(), insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop(), insets.getSystemWindowInsetRight(), insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom());
        //StatusBarHeight = insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();

        //Refresh/Adjust view accordingly

        return insets;
    }
}
```

Please excuse me if the code isn't 100% correct, converted it from Xamarin C# but this is the just of it. Works with Notches, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Toggled Fullscreen Solution:**

This solution may look like a workaround, but it actually accounts for whether your app is fullscreen (aka hiding the status bar) or not:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size);
int barheight = size.y - findViewById(R.id.rootView).getHeight();
```

This way, if your app is currently fullscreen, `barheight` will equal 0.

Personally I had to use this to correct absolute TouchEvent coordinates to account for the status bar as so:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size);
    int YCoord = (int)event.getRawY() - size.y + rootView.getHeight());
}
```

And that will get the absolute y-coordinate whether the app be fullscreen or not.

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution that worked for me when the android keyboard is showing too.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the top answer does not work for some people is because you cannot get the dimensions of a view until it is ready to render. Use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to get said dimensions when you actually can:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                // Nice one, Google
                decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
            rect.top; // This is the height of the status bar
        }
    }
}
```

This is the most reliable method.

Comment: @androiddeveloper OnGlobal != GlobalOn

Comment: @marijnz0r How odd. What's the deal with that?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't know, but I happened to think the same as you did a few days ago as well. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19216041/4587214

Comment: @marijnz0r So both do the same. Reminds me of other cases that they gave a new name for a stuff that already existed, and deprecated the previous one. Example "fill_parent" vs "match_parent" : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! Thanks!

Comment: @androiddeveloper, basically this will work for getting StatusBar Height or not?? because i have tried some of the other solutions also but right now this seems like better than other..

Comment: @VivekThummar I don't know. Was a long time ago. Sorry

Comment: it's okk and Thank you..

Comment: This is the correct answer. thank you

Answer (score 3):

On Android 4.1 and higher, you can set your application's content to appear behind the status bar, so that the content doesn't resize as the status bar hides and shows. To do this, use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN. You may also need to use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE to help your app maintain a stable layout.

When you use this approach, it becomes your responsibility to ensure that critical parts of your app's UI (for example, the built-in controls in a Maps application) don't end up getting covered by system bars. This could make your app unusable. In most cases you can handle this by adding the android:fitsSystemWindows attribute to your XML layout file, set to true. This adjusts the padding of the parent ViewGroup to leave space for the system windows. This is sufficient for most applications.

In some cases, however, you may need to modify the default padding to get the desired layout for your app. To directly manipulate how your content lays out relative to the system bars (which occupy a space known as the window's "content insets"), override fitSystemWindows(Rect insets). The fitSystemWindows() method is called by the view hierarchy when the content insets for a window have changed, to allow the window to adjust its content accordingly. By overriding this method you can handle the insets (and hence your app's layout) however you want.

form:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#behind

Answer (score 3):

Since multi-window mode is available now, your app may not have statusbar on top.

Following solution handle all the cases automatically for you.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

or programatically

```
findViewById(R.id.your_root_view).setFitsSystemWindows(true);
```

you may also get root view by

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
or
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

For more details on getting root-view refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488149/9640177

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly the size VS height

like

for example in a device with 320 X 480 screen size the status bar height is 25px, for a device with 480 x 800 the status bar height must be 38px

then you can just get the width of your view / the screen size you can just use an if else statement to get the height of status bar

Comment: In my experience, the height appears to be based upon density rather than screen size.  Of course, density itself is typically related to screen size, so there is an indirect relationship.  My old Moto Droid, for example, has a 480x854 (rather than 480x800) display, and the status bar is also 38 pixels high.

Comment: They invented dp for this (density independant pixels)

Answer (score 1):

This issue recently became relevant for me because of the notch in my Pixel 3XL.  I really liked [android developer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28965901/4520965), but I wanted to be able to get the status bar height at will, since it was specifically necessary for a full screen animation that I needed to play.  The function below enabled a reliable query:

```
private val DEFAULT_INSET = 96
fun getInsets(view: View?): Int {
     var inset = DEFAULT_INSET
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {//Safe because only P supports notches
          inset = view?.rootWindowInsets?.stableInsetTop ?: DEFAULT_INSET
     }
     return inset
}

fun blurView(rootView: View?, a: SpacesActivity?) {
    val screenBitmap = getBitmapFromView(rootView!!)
    val heightDifference = getInsets(rootView)
    val croppedMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    screenBitmap, 0, heightDifference,
                    screenBitmap.width,
                    screenBitmap.height - heightDifference)
    val blurredScreen = blurBitmap(croppedMap)
    if (blurredScreen != null) {
         val myDrawable = BitmapDrawable(a!!.resources, blurredScreen)
         a.errorHudFrameLayout?.background = myDrawable
         a.appBarLayout?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
   }
}
```

And then in the activity class:

```
fun blurView() {
    this.runOnUiThread {
        Helper.blurView(this)
    }
}
```

You will of course want to make pass a weak reference of the activity to the static Helper class method parameter, but for the sake of brevity I refrained in this example. The `blurBitmap`and `errorHudFrameLayout` are omitted for the same reason, since they don't directly pertain to obtaining the height of the status bar.

Comment: If it's for Android P and above, why check with Android M ? Also, what would you do if you don't have a View instance? For example if you don't have an Activity currently...

Comment: M is the earliest that you could check stableInsetTop, and even though only P supported notches I'd rather get the actual inset were possible instead of falling back to the default where I can.  This solution doesn't work if you don't have an activity.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Can you please show a more "full" example?

Comment: I changed my answer above to use the method in an example.