# Get root view from current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, view

I know how to get the root view with [View.getRootView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView%28%29). I am also able to get the view from a button's `onClick` event where the argument is a [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). But how can I get the **view** in an [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)?

Comment: In activity, normally you tell which resource it should render using `setContentView()` and the view that you supplied is already the root. If you need the handle of that view, simply put an ID to it in XAML and `findViewById()` would be fine.

Comment: My plan is to attach the code dynamically .. so if my users use the api I expect it to be automatically detect things.. Boulder's solution works !

Comment: @xandy: a slight typo: XAML -> XML.

Answer (score 1171, accepted):

If you need root view of your activity (so you can add your contents there) use

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```

Also it was reported that on some devices you have to use

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

instead.

Please note that as Booger reported, this may be behind navigation bar (with back button etc.) on some devices (but it seems on most devices it is not).

If you need to get view that you added to your activity using `setContentView()` method then as pottedmeat wrote you can use

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

But better just set id to this view in your xml layout and use this id instead.

Comment: Actually just findViewById(android.R.id.content) is giving me the root view. If that is not true in some cases I can get root view from the findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView(). Thanks for the answer. Where can I learn more about android.R stuff ? I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: You can check here I suppose http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html It's just android resources reference. Personally I learned about android.R.id.content then checking layouts in hierarchyviewer.

Comment: I've noticed that this view appears to include the status bar, so if you're looking for the visible part of your activity, use the answer from @pottedmeat.

Comment: @Lalith, can you elaborate on when you needed to do findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()? A general rule would be really useful to know.

Comment: @batbrat I need to use .getRootView() in Android 5.0+ when using action bar

Comment: When you use this answer, your Snackbar will include the system decor (meaning the Snackbar information will appear behind the Navigation Buttons - Home/Back/Recents).  I need my Snackbar to appear in MY Activity (not the entire system, including the on-screen nav buttons), so use the other answer.

Comment: @nickes,how to get the rootview of fragment??

Comment: @VikramSingh call `getView()` in Fragment.

Comment: @batbrat: IIRC, if you already have the root view, `view.getRootView()` will return that root view (again). I mean, it is harmless to add `.getRootView()`, so the safe answer is to *always* do `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()`. [Unless you want the root of content, in which case the `.getChildAt(0)` is what you want.]

Comment: `activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)` is returning null in Android 5. :(

Comment: @JuanJoséMeleroGómez Is it consistent for all Android 5 devices or is it only for your device?

Comment: You're right, @DmitryRyadnenko, it only happens in my device. It's a Samsung SM-T365. I had to go with `getWindow().getDecorView()` on it.

Comment: Perfect working. Without this approach it misbehave to give rootview of activity

Comment: "it was reported that on some devices you have to use
`getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)`" Can you specify which devices?

Comment: Also answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76529993/4134215

Answer (score 280):

This is what I use to get the root view as found in the XML file assigned with `setContentView`:

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

Comment: This answer gave the view without the status bar - which is what I wanted. I was looking for the pixel width + height of the visible part of the activity. This one works, thanks!

Comment: This excludes ActionBar!

Comment: Is there a way to include the `ActionBar` as well?

Comment: The key words here are "the root view as found in the XML file". Thank you.

Comment: This should be the correct marked answer.  This will place the Snackbar inside your Activity (at the root), which is where it should be (I am pretty sure nobody wants to place their info behind the Nav Buttons)

Comment: why is the use of getChildAt(0) ? Anyone?

Comment: `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getHeight();` will get you the height of the root View

Answer (score 150):

I tested this in android 4.0.3, only:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()
```

give the same view what we get from

```
anyview.getRootView();

com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@#########
```

and

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

giving child of its

```
android.widget.FrameLayout@#######
```

Please confirm.

Comment: Android2.3.3 seems same

Comment: Works in 4.3
Is the easiest way and the least amount of code I've found.

Comment: Best if you're using SnackBar

Comment: *getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getHeight()* returns display height.

Comment: getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() is not recommended for snack bar, it will overlap the system navigation bar, findViewById(android.R.id.content) will be better.

Answer (score 37):

#### Get root view from current activity.

Inside our activity we can get the `root` view with:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

or

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

Answer (score 35):

In Kotlin we can do it a little shorter:

```
val rootView = window.decorView.rootView
```

Comment: it, take the root of windows, if you show a snack it show the message in navigation bar

Answer (score 22):

Just incase Someone needs an easier way:

The following code gives a view of the whole activity:

`View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();`

To get a certian view in the activity,for example an imageView inside the activity, simply add the id of that view you want to get:

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: You can just call `findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` on the activity if you want the specific view.

Answer (score 11):

### Kotlin Extension Solution

Use this to simplify access in an Activity. Then you can directly refer to `rootView` from the Activity, or `activity.rootView` outside of it:

```
val Activity.rootView get() = window.decorView.rootView
```

If you'd like to add the same for Fragments for consistency, add:

```
val Fragment.rootView get() = view?.rootView
```

Answer (score 8):

For those of you who are using the [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding), to get the root of the current activity, simply use:

```
View rootView = dataBinding.getRoot();
```

And for Kotlin users, it's even simpler:

```
val rootView = dataBinding.root
```

Comment: I think this should be upvoted especially now that data binding is the supported library for working with views. Data binding makes this process a lot simpler!

Answer (score 5):

`anyview.getRootView();` will be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

to get View of the current Activity

in any onClick we will be getting "View view", by using 'view' get the rootView.

View view = view.getRootView();

and to get View in fragment

View view = FragmentClass.getView();

Answer (score 1):

### Another Kotlin Extension solution

If your activity's view is declared in xml (ex `activity_root.xml`), open the xml and assign an id to the root view:

```
android:id="@+id/root_activity"
```

Now in your class, import the view using:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_root.root_activity
```

You can now use `root_activity` as the view.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in a activity, assume there is only one root view,you can get it like this.

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
        .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

you can then cast it to your real class

or you could using

```
getWindow().getDecorView();
```

notice this will include the actionbar view, your view is below the actionbar view

Comment: There is no such method in `Activity` class.

Comment: window.decorView or window.decorView as ViewGroup - if you need to cast it to the ViewGroup