# Any easy, generic way in Android to get the root View of a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm wondering if there is a general-purpose method in the Android Activity class to allow you to get the root View of that Activity's layout. I know I can do it this way:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.root_view_id)
```

But I would like to be able to do it without having to pass in the ID of the root view. I need to do this for a lot of different Activities, and it would be a lot more convenient if I had a one-size-fits-all method call to accomplish the task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : How to get root view from current activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/android-how-to-get-root-view-from-current-activity)

Comment: @rds You linked it with wrong question imo

Comment: @TGMCians Oops, the technique can be the same, but the questions are indeed different. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/android-how-to-get-root-view-from-current-activity/4488149#4488149) and comments give one method:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Given any view in your hierarchy you can also call:

```
view.getRootView()
```

to obtain the root view of that hierarchy.

The "decor view" can also be obtained via `getWindow().getDecorView()`. This is the root of the view hierarchy and the point where it attaches to the window, but I'm not sure you want to be messing with it directly.

Comment: That did the trick! I will accept this answer as soon as StackOverflow allows me to.

Comment: @Matthew willis,how to get the rootview of fragment??

Comment: @VikramSingh please use the search function and if your question has not yet been asked, post your question.