# Access Activity views for third-party libraries and change text

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-view, android-fragmentactivity

I have a third-party library added in my project that launches an `Activity`.

Is there any way I can access that `Activity`/`Fragment`'s view and change its text programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Exactly* what to do depends pretty heavily on the third-party library, and it's surely unsupported by the library and might break with library updates, but generally, you could [register](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) an [`ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) on your `Application` context.  You'll get a reference to the `Activity` in the callbacks.  From there, you could [get the root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488509/any-easy-generic-way-in-android-to-get-the-root-view-of-a-layout) and either use `findViewById` if you know the ID, walk the tree and look for the text you're expecting, or use some other way of recognizing it (maybe the class of the view, or its location in the structure).

Fragments can be retrieved by getting the `FragmentManager` and calling [`getFragments()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#getFragments()).  Note that you'll need to know whether it uses the framework `FragmentManager` or the one from `androidx`/`android.support` to know whether to use `getFragmentManager()` or [`getSupportFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager()).

Comment: Is there any way that i can access the fragment too?

Comment: Yep, you can iterate through the fragment manager's fragments and use similar techniques to figure out which one (unless there's only one, then it's easy).  Expanded on that a bit in the answer.