# getContentView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources

Given an activity how can I retrieve the contentView? That is, the first view in the activity hierarchy without knowing it id?

Something like the inverse of setContentView();

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/android-how-to-get-root-view-from-current-activity