# android redraw layout programmatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My layout sometimes does not position elements properly. I tried a lot of solutions but unique working one is rotate from portrait to landscape and then return from landscape to portrait. Then layout is automaticaly redrawed and fits perfectly. I set orientation|keyboard so content is not reloaded, only redrawed. How to redraw content programmaticaly like landscape-portrait does? Thank you.

EDIT: I tried following and has no effect

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
```

Activity has set main layout on onCreate `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Layout "main" contains a TabHost and Admob.
Layout "view" contains a webview ("id:myWebview") that is shown on tab1.

And also tried to invalidate them! webview, layout main and layout view and crashes

Comment: What does "sometimes" means? Is there any reproducible way to get the error? Have you tried requestLayout to force to redraw the layout? Can you put some sample code to show what kind of and views are you using?

Comment: You could try calling `invalidate()` to force a view to redraw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try to [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) the [root view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4486034/559745)?

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
```

This should redraw the whole layout.

Comment: Would that cause `setContentView()` to be called?

Comment: in kotlin i called layout directly By Id i.e. `llHint.invalidate()` but it's not working i mean no clear whole layout which contain textview, edittext etc.

Answer (score 2):

When screen orientation changes, Android recreates the current Activity.

Try calling [measure(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure%28int,%20int%29) or [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29). Otherwise there is no chance to programmatically relayout views.

Answer (score 1):

Call [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) only and read [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class description for more informations.

Answer (score -1):

If this is unsafe or bad practice please do correct me. I tried all these methods as well and out of desperation decided to just try calling my onCreate again and it worked. So for now I'll be using `onCreate(null)` to refresh my view when I update data. Again, please let me know if this is unsafe or a bad practice and if possible a working alternative.