# Change image in ImageView

Tags: java, android

In list_item.xml file I have a ImageView and one TextView. The code of ImageView is given as

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/play"/>
```

In main activity (main_activity.java is connected with activity_main.xml, which have one ListView), the music is playing well when user click on music (onItemClick) from list set with setAdapter. Now I want to change the image of this ImageView, when music start to play, when . So I inserted the code as given below:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
ImageView imgchange = (ImageView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.play);
imgchange.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
```

But it is not working. I also tried

```
android:src="@drawable/imagename"
```

I also tried

```
imgchange.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
```

Looking for valuable advise as how can I do it or where is the mistake?

Comment: Try this after setting imsgeresource :: imgchange.drawableStateChanged()

Comment: Show me your MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the new `ContextCompat` instead of `setBackgroundResource()`, like this:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.pause));
```

You can pass your `Activity` as the `Context`. If that does not work, you can also try to invalidate your view, which will force a redraw.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried imgchange.invalidate(); and then insert setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause), but no luck. I also tried the code ContextCompat but it is showing error

Comment: Wow, now it's working but image size is creating a problem. As it is now exceeding and overlapping with TextView

Comment: You can give your ImageView a predefined height and width, you can also specify the scaletype.

Comment: Yup, u r right. Thanks a lot. Can I also add animation to this ? like when music play animation start, instead of just changing one image. Is that i can do in same way? As for this I create one anim.xml file in drawable

Comment: Yes, but we cannot discuss that here. Please mark this as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past and it was caused by the fact that the layout didn't updated itself. Try to refresh the layout of the view after you changed the image as described here [android redraw layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347823/android-redraw-layout-programmatically)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried, but no luck