# how to take screen shot of a running video in android programatically?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-videoview

I have made a simple demo app in android,In that i have made a custom video player with play pause,capture etc controls.Now i want is that on "capture" button click my running video's screen shot should be taken and set to an imageview i have taken in same activity.I have tried as below which is not working ,please help me for the problem:

**Main.java**

```
mcaptur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                img_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                View v1 = view.getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b = v1.getDrawingCache();

                img_view.setImageBitmap(b);

                /*
                 * screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); bmScreen =
                 * screen.getDrawingCache(); showDialog(ID_SCREENDIALOG);
                 */
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/             Another  Link ----  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430418/capture-screen-shot-on-android-using-java-code

Answer (score 0):

hope this code helps

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


 @Override


  public void onClick(View v) {
   Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();

   }
```

});

see this

public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

```
View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();


 rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


  return rootView.getDrawingCache();
```

}