# Navigation Bar in Android: size and position

Tags: android, navigationbar

I'm currently developing an OpenGL app for Android. Everything works fine so far, but the navigation bar is a little bit disturbing...

Is there a way to find out if the navigation bar is on the right side like on my galaxy nexus when in landscape or if it is on the bottom like on tablets.
In addition I need the height and width of the navigation bar.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this??

Thanks

Comment: By navigation bar you mean the one with the home, back button ?

Comment: Right. For my glViewport I want to substract the widht or hight of the  bar depending on the orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting here for benefit of those who end up here looking for ways to elegantly handle Navigationbar and Statusbar.

Refer [this post](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/88b4e26ba3ff).

As suggested in many of similar questions, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29938139/9640177), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26118045/9640177), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50775459/9640177), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41057024/9640177), simply getting navigation bar height may not be enough. We need to consider whether *1. navigation bar exists, 2. is it on the bottom, or right or left, 3. is app open in multi-window mode.*

**There is a simple one line solution**

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

or programatically

```
findViewById(R.id.your_root_view).setFitsSystemWindows(true);
```

you may also get root view by

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
or
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

For more details on getting root-view refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488149/9640177

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size); 
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
```

After this part of code, width and height are containing the height and the width without the navigation bar or notification bar.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in this way:

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext())
                .hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

//if there is not menu key then there is navigation bar

```
if (!hasMenuKey && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
         DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            if (dm.heightPixels%10!=0) {
            //navigation bar is on bottom
            } else {
               //navigation bar is on right side
            }

        }
```

Comment: and if you have a device whose height will be 768px when rotated? height%10 != 0 will return `true` but the navigation bar is on the right.. Have you found any more reliable solution to check the navigation bar position?

Comment: On that time it was the only solution I found for more devices. However I still could not find good solution