# What is the alternative for getRealMetrics in android to get screen original size

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigation, android-windowmanager

In my android application I need to find out if the device is having a navigation bar or not. For that I am getting the device original screen size and application window size. Based on that I am calculating the difference and so I can find out if the device is having a navigation bar or not.
Here is the code I use:

```
public static boolean hasSoftKeys(WindowManager windowManager){
    Display d = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    DisplayMetrics realDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    d.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);

    int realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    d.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    return (realWidth - displayWidth) > 0 || (realHeight - displayHeight) > 0;
}
```

The problem is: Calling the "`getRealMetrics`" method requires api level 17. Here I need a solution for the lower version devices which will give the same result like `getRealMetrics` to get the original screen size. I did not find any solution.

Can anybody suggest me any alternative for `getRealMetrics` which will work for the lower version devices ?

Here is my investigation to find out the navigation bar availability. It is not a reliable result on all devices.

**Code1:**

```
boolean hasNavBar(Context context) {

        boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
        boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
        return !hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey;
    }
```

**Code2**

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

By using this code we can check if the device has PermanentMenuKey. But it is not the meaning device which don't have PermanentMenuKey is having soft navigation bar.

Comment: Relevant post with answer is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983621/detect-soft-navigation-bar-availability-in-android-device-progmatically/32698387#32698387

Answer (score -1):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: This will give the size of window occupied by the application activity. But not the original size of the window. I have the same code in by question. Please verify the code added in the question.