# Detect soft navigation bar availability in onePlusOne device progmatically?

Tags: android

I need to check if a device has the soft navigation bar, and I followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983621/detect-soft-navigation-bar-availability-in-android-device-progmatically).

It works great, except on onePlus devices, for some reason, this code:

```
int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", android");
    return id > 0 && resources.getBoolean(id);
```

returns false, although the soft navigation bar is displayed.

Any idea how can I get the correct result?

I prefer not to calculate the real width and available width, it seems like expensive operation.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes.
Eventually, I used this code:

 public boolean hasNavBar() {
        Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getRealMetrics(dm);

        int realHeight = dm.heightPixels;
        int realWidth = dm.widthPixels;
        d.getMetrics(dm);

        int displayHeight = dm.heightPixels;
        int displayWidth = dm.widthPixels;

        return (realWidth - displayWidth) > 0 || (realHeight - displayHeight) > 0;
    }

This gave the best result on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23181183/5138665) answer. There is no way be 100% sure, though.

```
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

if (hasBackKey && hasHomeKey) {
    // no navigation bar, unless it is enabled in the settings
} else {
    // 99% sure there's a navigation bar
}
```

**Edit**

Another approach

```
public boolean hasNavBar (Resources resources) {
    int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
    return id > 0 && resources.getBoolean(id);
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work on devices like HTC one which has custom ROM

Comment: @SureshKumar See the edit. It's an alternate solution.

Comment: It always returns true on SamSung A70

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try this:

```
    WindowManager mgr = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            boolean hasSoftKey = Utils.hasSoftKeys(mgr, NPTApplication.this);

public static boolean hasSoftKeys(WindowManager windowManager, Context c) {
        boolean hasSoftwareKeys = true;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            Display d = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

            DisplayMetrics realDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            d.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);

            int realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            d.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

            hasSoftwareKeys = (realWidth - displayWidth) > 0 || (realHeight - displayHeight) > 0;
        } else {
            boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(c).hasPermanentMenuKey();
            boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
            hasSoftwareKeys = !hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey;
        }
        return hasSoftwareKeys;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

no will not work that way you have to compute the size

the method used is detailed in this SO answer;

[How to get height and width of navigation bar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264268/how-to-get-height-and-width-of-navigation-bar-programmatically/29609679#29609679)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a method `hasPermanentMenuKey` which checks if the hardware `MenuKey` is present, usually Samsung devices has it on left size of `Home` button.

So if it returns true, it means the phone has hardware keys, and if it's false, then simply it means phone has navigation bar.

The method is:

```
ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey()
```

I find it pretty useful for myself.

Comment: This doesnt work on devices like HTC one and one plus one . This always returns true

Answer (score 0):

//The method has ability to return 0 when the navigation bar was hidden.

```
private fun getNavigationBarHeight(context: Context): Int {
    val display = context.windowManager?.defaultDisplay
    return if (display == null) {
        0
    } else {
        val realMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        display.getRealMetrics(realMetrics)
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
        display.getMetrics(metrics)
        realMetrics.heightPixels - metrics.heightPixels
    }
}
```