# Check if Samsung S8 is in full screen mode

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

Is there a way to check if the device is in full screen mode in the new Samsung S8? I tried solutions added to this post but everything returns true.
[Detect soft navigation bar availability in android device progmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983621/detect-soft-navigation-bar-availability-in-android-device-progmatically)

I can get the correct visibility listening to `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` as shown below:

```
private class MyOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener implements View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if (visibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) {
           // full screen mode
        } else {
           // not full screen mode
        }
    }
}
```

The above method only works when the user triggers full screen by pressing on the soft navigation button but I need to check if the device is already in full screen mode when it entered the app.

Answer (score 0):

just call on a View `View.getSystemUiVisibility()` and compare to the same `int`