# Android 11 Full screen with Coordinator layout status bar spacing issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-11, android-fullscreen, windowinsets

I am facing an issue with the full-screen immersive mode in Android 11. My Main activity layout file look something like this,

```
<DrawerLayout .... android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <CoordinatorLayout>
          <AppBarLayout>
              <FragmentContainerView>
```

I am trying to show a full-screen mode from my Fragment.
Pre Android 11, I used to call the below function from my Fragment's onCreate view

```
fun hideStatusBar (activity: AppCompatActivity?) {
activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) }
```

I replaced that with,

```
fun hideStatusBar(activity: AppCompatActivity?) {
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
if (isAtLeastAndroid11()) {
    val controller = activity?.window?.insetsController
    controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
} else {
    activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
}
```

This removes the status bar as intended but leaves a blank space at the top of the screen in the status bar area

With status bar:

[image]

Status bar removed:

[image]

I tried to measure the Window Insets inside my fragment and adjust the height of my fragment container

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    if(isAtLeastAndroid11()){
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(requireActivity().window, false)
        setUiWindowInsets()
    }
}

private fun setUiWindowInsets() {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(rootView) { _, insets ->
    
        posTop = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).top
        posBottom = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).bottom

        rootView.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            updateMargins(
                top = posTop,
                bottom = posBottom)
        }

        insets
    }
}
```

But my ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener is never called. As per this article, Coordinator Layout consumes onApplyWindowInsets callbacks and the child won't get any callbacks. `rootView` is the root view of my Fragment (a relative layout) which was placed in FragmentContainer in my layout hierarchy.

Comparison between Android 10 and 11

[image]

My Question:

1. How should I get the call to my `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` method in fragment?
2. How should I let my coordinator layout know to occupy full screen when status bar is hidden?

References:
Coordinator layout consumes callbacks:

1. [setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062834/setonapplywindowinsetslistener-never-called?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec
3. https://newbedev.com/fitssystemwindows-effect-gone-for-fragments-added-via-fragmenttransaction

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the App bar. even though it is full screen it will try to prevent content from colliding with status bar even if it is hidden. this is a new implementation also to prevent the phone notch from covering content.

You should remove the app bar if you want to utilize the whole screen. if really need a tooltip for actions use a bottom bar.

Comment: Thank you, when you say remove - you mean to remove completely from layout or just hide it when I need full screen. I will try and update

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set `fitsSystemWindows` flag off (where `window` is Window instance):

```
window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
```

So I do like this:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
    }
}
```

Of course, you also need to set the flag on when showing status bar:

```
private void showSystemUI() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true);
    }
}
```

---

FYI, you may have to trigger `hideSystemUI` or `showSystemUI` in `Activity.onWindowFocusChanged`.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        if (isImmersive) {
            hideSystemUI();
        } else {
            showSystemUI();
        }
    }
}
```

(above is in Java. Please translate it into Kotlin)

Comment: I have `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` in `onActivityCreated()`. I moved that to `hideSystemUI()` as you suggested, which I am calling from `onViewCreated()`. It has no effect.

Comment: @Madhan I updated my answer. You may have to override `onWindowFocusChanged`.

Comment: `onWindowFocusChanged` is called once when the activity loads for the first time, I launch full screen from a fragment. I don't receive any callback in `onWindowFocusChanged` when fragment expands to full screen. Do you know why I am not receiving any calls to `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` in Fragment which sets the margin?

Comment: @Madhan I have no idea about that.