# How to detect full screen gesture mode in android 10

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

In Android 10, users can enable full screen gesture mode. I want to detect whether the device in full screen gesture mode or not. I can't find anything in documentation. How to do it programmatically at run time?

Java or kotlin language answer is OK.

Any official API or workaround...

Comment: Do these articles help you ? https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive | https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

Comment: I already read it. But can't find any good solution. We can calculate using system bars, but it is not suitable for all devices & apps, since it is non-standard!

Comment: Do you mean "fully gestural navigation" by "full screen gestures"?

Comment: I think both are same. Try android Q beta 4...

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately,  No!

Comment: @Jaya Prakash Almost 2 year later, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @A_Jayke Not yet. I still can't believe they didn't include any API for this. :/

Answer (score 25):

You can use below code to check gesture or navigation mode

```
    public static int isEdgeToEdgeEnabled(Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("config_navBarInteractionMode", "integer", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            return resources.getInteger(resourceId);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The value that returned by isEdgeToEdgeEnabled function will follow below:

- 0 : Navigation is displaying with 3 buttons
- 1 : Navigation is displaying with 2 button(Android P navigation mode)
- 2 : Full screen gesture(Gesture on android Q)

Comment: Is using resource identifier reliable? I read that they vary depends on device & may change over time...

Comment: I found the resource identifier on android Q source code of google. so I think that OEMs will use same id for full screen gesture.

Comment: Important! You need to surround `resources.getInteger()` with try/catch to handle Resources.NotFoundException, otherwise this code will crash on various Xiaomi and Samsung devices. Also this code didn't work on Huawei devices.

Comment: In my case (S21 Ultra, Android 11) config_navBarInteractionMode = 17694897, so this method is not very reliable

Comment: this is not working. I tried on xioami device. it both gives 0 in gesture and menu buttons mode

Comment: Unfortunately not working on Android T (Pixel 6a)

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-handling-visual-overlaps-4aed565c134c) really useful in explaining what [`WindowInsets`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets) are and how to use them.

Basically I check if the left gesture inset is greater than `0`, and if it is then the system is using gesture type navigation. Left and right gesture insets have to be greater than `0` in gesture type navigation because you swipe from the right or left to go back.

```java
int gestureLeft = 0;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
    gestureLeft = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootWindowInsets().getSystemGestureInsets().left;
}

if (gestureLeft == 0) {
    // Doesn't use gesture type navigation
} else {
    // Uses gesture type navigation
}
```

Obviously, the window has to be rendered for this to work. You can add it inside an [`OnApplyWindowInsetsListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) if you want this to run as soon as the window is rendered.

> Note: I tried using `getSystemGestureInsets().bottom`, but it returned a non-zero value even when I wasn't using gesture type navigation.

Comment: Did you tried after hiding the bottom-gesture-indicator bar?

Comment: @JayaPrakash No I don't hide that bar, but it should still work.

Comment: Did not work for redmi :(

Answer (score -1):

According to docs, there is a `hasInsets()` method that returns `true` if the `WindowInsets` has any nonzero insets.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets#hasInsets()
We can use it this way

```
view.rootWindowInsets.hasInsets()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It returns true, even in gesture mode!

Comment: It should return true for gestures mode. False otherwise. Does it behave accordingly?

Comment: It returns true for both gesture mode and non-gesture mode.