# How can app get the mode of the navigation bar

Tags: android

It means, how the app get the navigation bar mode in which of the following 3 modes

- gesture navigation
- 3-button navigation
- 2-button navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code , may not work on all android devices

```
public static int isEdgeToEdgeEnabled(Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("config_navBarInteractionMode", "integer", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            return resources.getInteger(resourceId);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The value that returned by isEdgeToEdgeEnabled function will follow below:

- Navigation is displaying with 3 buttons
- Navigation is displaying with 2 button(Android P navigation mode)
- Full screen gesture(Gesture on android Q)

Comment: References from answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624920/how-to-detect-full-screen-gesture-mode-in-mi-devices-programmatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689210/how-to-detect-full-screen-gesture-mode-in-android-10)

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.provider.Settings

enum class SystemNavigation {
    THREE_BUTTON,
    TWO_BUTTON,
    GESTURE;

    companion object {
        fun create(context: Context) = values().getOrNull(
            Settings.Secure.getInt(context.contentResolver, "navigation_mode", -1)
        )
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```kotlin
val systemNavigation = SystemNavigation.create(context)
```