# Get System Navigation Type

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I determine the type of system navigation being used (gesture navigation or 2-/3-key navigation)? I want to add a background color for a certain type of system navigation.

```kotlin
val view = LocalView.current 
val window = (view.context as Activity).window

if (!view.isInEditMode) { 
    SideEffect {
        window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
        window.navigationBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb() // TODO

        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).apply {
            isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
            isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can app get the mode of the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813787/how-can-app-get-the-mode-of-the-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0):

These two ways are restricted by [non-SDK interfaces restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)***(*reflection required*)***:

1. if you call `PackageManager#getInstalledApplications`, you'll see some applications' package name contains "systemui.navbar", they belongs to Runtime Resource Overlay(RRO) packages which their `isResourceOverlay()` returns `true`. System use `android.content.om.OverlayManager` to manage overlay packages and `android.content.om.OverlayInfo` to get enable state.
2. use `getResources().getInteger()` with `com.android.internal.R$integer#config_navBarInteractionMode` to get
   value `android.view.WindowManagerPolicyConstants#NAV_BAR_MODE_*`

---

so...

after several tries...
*(Java)*

gesture navigation maybe smaller than or equals to status bar normally, so if it's larger, i think it's 2/3-button.

***based on `API level 29`, see [WindowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowInsets) or compat.***

```java
//...

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Insets;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowInsets;
import android.view.WindowInsets$Type;
import android.os.Build;
//...

private boolean isAndroidR = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R;

view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((View v, WindowInsets i) -> {
  Insets inset = isAndroidR 
    //or getInsetsIgnoringVisibility
    ? i.getInsets(
      Type.statusBars() | Type.navigationBars()
    )
    //or getStableInsets
    : i.getSystemWindowInsets();
  //some devices' height maybe 0
  int status, navigation;
  //the height difference of gesture navigation and notification bar is small
  boolean isGestureNavigation =
    //maybe 0 if hidden, use getInsetsIgnoringVisibility/getStableInsets
    (status = inset.top) != 0 &&
      //some system may provide an option to always hide gesture navigation, so always 0
      (navigation = inset.bottom) != 0 &&
      status >= navigation;
  //do something

  getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(
    isGestureNavigation ? Color.TRANSPARENT : Color.BLUE
  );

  return i;//isAndroidR ? WindowInsets.CONSUMED : i.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
});

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

See [How can app get the mode of the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813787/how-can-app-get-the-mode-of-the-navigation-bar)

```kotlin
enum class SystemNavigation {
    THREE_BUTTON,
    TWO_BUTTON,
    GESTURE;
    companion object {
        fun create(context: Context) = values().getOrNull(
            Settings.Secure.getInt(context.contentResolver, "navigation_mode", -1)
        )
    }
}

val view = LocalView.current
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme

        when(SystemNavigation.create(context)) {
            SystemNavigation.THREE_BUTTON,
            SystemNavigation.TWO_BUTTON -> {
                window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.surface.copy(alpha = 0.96f).toArgb()
                WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme
            }
            SystemNavigation.GESTURE -> {
                window.navigationBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
            }
            else -> { // Older apis do not have a callback, so completing this section is recommended. I'm dublicate THREE_BUTTON and TWO_BUTTON. }
        }
    }
}
```