# Detect change keyboard button in soft navigation bar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, keyboard

I need to be able to detect if the change keyboard button is available on the bottom navigation bar.

From what I've gathered the button will be present if two conditions are met

1. There is at least one additional custom keyboard installed
2. Soft keys are present on bottom bar.

I've used [Detect soft navigation bar availability in android device progmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983621/detect-soft-navigation-bar-availability-in-android-device-progmatically) to detect if soft navigation bar is available successfully, however I'd want something more fool proof and less hacky. The above method will fail for example if gesture navigation is turned on, and probably there are many more edge cases not covered by the above method.

[image]