# How to detect whether gesture navigation or button navigation is active?

Tags: android, flutter

After Android 10, users can prefer gesture navigation mode. I want to detect whether the device in gesture navigation mode or not. I will change the design with respect to system navigation preference.

I can't find anything in documentation. How to do it?

Do you have any official API or workaround?

Comment: I need to know as well.  The gesture navigation seems to add a little line at the bottom of the screen, taking up some real-estate.  I need to take this into account for my layouts.

Comment: Possible answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/74091225/556600

Answer (score 2):

From Android 30 onwards we can get system insets to check whether gesture navigation is enabled or not.

If gesture navigation is enabled, then `WindowInsets.Type.systemGestures()` will have values for `inset.left` and `inset.right` greater than 0.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            binding.root.apply {
                var hasGesture = false
                doOnAttach {
                    val inset = it.rootWindowInsets?.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.systemGestures())
                    println("inset: left: ${inset?.left} right: ${inset?.right} top:${inset?.top} bottom: ${inset?.bottom}")
                    val margin = it.rootWindowInsets?.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.systemGestures())?.left ?: 0
                    hasGesture = margin > 0
                }
            }
        }
```