# How to know if device has Navigation Bar

Tags: android, genymotion, navigationbar

How can I know programmatically if a device has a navigation bar and if it has it how can i get the size (width and height).

I tried this solution [stackoverflow.com/a/29938139/1683141](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29938139/1683141) and when I test a Sony Xperia Z on Genimotion, returns that not has a navigation bar but it has!

Please I need to fix this cases with navigation bar, because the app not looks good.

Thanks

Comment: instead of trying to use a hacky work around that may or may not work why dont you tell us what your UI looks like and how you want it to look

Comment: i want to know that,because the nav bar can´t dissapear forever

Comment: The reason that it returns 0, is because you are running on an emulator. The emulator has 'emulated' physical buttons, whereas an actual, physical device will not.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609679/2703209) to the question you linked. The difference between `appUsableSize` and `realScreenSize` is the space occupied by the navigation bar. (This works because, somewhat unexpectedly, the status bar counts toward `appUsableSize`.) If both sizes are the same, you have no navigation bar.