# Detect navigation bar visibility

Tags: java, android, galaxy

I am trying to check the visibility of the navigation bar. On the Samsung Galaxy S8 I can toggle the navigation bar visibility.

I have tried a lot of different ways to check the visibility, but none of them work on the Galaxy S8.

**Some examples: (They will always return the same value, no matter it is shown or hidden)**

`ViewConfiguration.get(getBaseContext()).hasPermanentMenuKey()` always returns `false`
`KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)` always returns `false`
`KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)` always returns `true`

Even by figuring out the navigation bar height ([How do I get the height and width of the Android Navigation Bar programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264268/how-do-i-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-android-navigation-bar-programmatically/29609679)), it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful for someone. The user can hide the navigation bar, so the best way to detect visibility is to subscribe to this event. It works.

```
 object NavigationBarUtils {
    // Location of navigation bar
    const val LOCATION_BOTTOM = 0
    const val LOCATION_RIGHT = 1
    const val LOCATION_LEFT = 2
    const val LOCATION_NONE = 3

    fun addLocationListener(activity: Activity, listener: (location: Int) -> Unit) {
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(activity.window.decorView) { view, insets ->
            val location = when {
                insets.systemWindowInsetBottom != 0 -> LOCATION_BOTTOM
                insets.systemWindowInsetRight != 0 -> LOCATION_RIGHT
                insets.systemWindowInsetLeft != 0 -> LOCATION_LEFT
                else -> LOCATION_NONE
            }
            listener(location)
            ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(view, insets)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the only answer at the time of writing is Kotlin, here is a Java alternative:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import android.view.View;

public class NavigationBar {

    final int BOTTOM = 0;
    final int RIGHT = 1;
    final int LEFT = 2;
    final int NONE = 3;
    private int LOCATION = NONE;

    private View view;

    NavigationBar(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    int getNavBarLocation() {
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view, new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                if (insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() != 0)
                    LOCATION = BOTTOM;
                else if (insets.getSystemWindowInsetRight() != 0)
                    LOCATION = RIGHT;
                else if (insets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft() != 0)
                    LOCATION = LEFT;
                else
                    LOCATION = NONE;
                return insets;
            }
        });
        return LOCATION;
    }

    int getNavBarHeight() {
        Resources resources = view.getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(
                "navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0)
            return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have also included how to get the height, since that will often be the next step.

In your activity, you would then call the methods using a view-based reference:

```
    NavigationBar navigationBar = new NavigationBar(snackbarLayout);
    if (navigationBar.getNavBarLocation() == navigationBar.BOTTOM) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams parentParams =
                (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) snackbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        parentParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0 - navigationBar.getNavBarHeight());
        snackbarLayout.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
    }
```

(This example is based on a common issue with inconsistent SnackBar margins)