# How to measure the height of the navigation bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a xamarin.forms application where I need to measure the height of the navigation bar. How do I measure it? I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264268/how-do-i-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-android-navigation-bar-programmatically) but I don't understand where to insert this code:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. The problem is that your app is cross platform and the navigation bar is a Android-only feature. Because you probably need to access the navigation bar height from within the shared code, you will need to use **Dependency injection**. This is [thoroughly described here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/).

In short you will have to write a namespace like this:

```
public interface INavigationBarInfo
{
    int Height { get; };
}
```

And implement it for Android within the Android project:

```
public class NavigationBarInfo : INavigationBarInfo
{
    public int Height => RetrieveHeight();

    private void RetrieveHeight()
    {
       //android specific code to retrieve the navigation bar height
       //you can use the answer you linked to in your question          
    }
}
```