# snackbar height is doubled in NoActionBar themes

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I use NoActionBar them to activity like this:

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and i try to set full screen like this:

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    AppLog.Log(TAG, "hasFocus: " + hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
```

but my snackbar height is doubled like this:

[image]

why snackbar height is doubled in NoActionBar themes??

Comment: I think it is due to you hiding the navigation and not due to the actionbar being missing. What happens if you remove the full screen flags and this: | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snackbar is taking up the space of the previous Actionbar. Use this to fix it:

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content),
            message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();

//One way of getting the height of the navBar
int navbarHeight = getNavigationBarSize(this).y;

//The LayoutParams of the layout you are using
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbarView.getLayoutParams();
    parentParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0 - ScreenUtils.getNavigationBarHeight(activity));
    snackbarView.setLayoutParams(parentParams);

snackbar.show();
```

**Explanation:**
There are 2 ways to get the height of the Navbar.

```
getNavigationBarSize(this).y;
```

or

```
ScreenUtils.getNavigationBarHeight(activity));
```

Use either of then and subtract that amount from the **margin bottom** of the parent layout.

Use appropriate layout params like **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** or **LinearLayout.LayoutParams** if you are using Relative or Linear layout

Comment: and how to use **navbarHeight**?

Comment: You don't need to use it. It's just another way of getting the height of the ActionBar

Comment: I use this to get the navigation bar height: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264361/3260008

Comment: This is not actually changing the height of the Snackbar, it's just adding a negative margin and hiding the bottom half of it. As a result you lose the rounded corners and it doesn't look correct so this solution is not strictly correct.