# BottomSheetDialogFragment overlaps navigation bar

Tags: android, navigationbar, bottom-sheet

I've issue with enter/exit transition of BottomSheetDialogFragment. For some reason animation overlaps system navigation bar.

Is there any way to prevent bottom sheet from overlapping navigation bar?

[image: Gif showing an issue]

Comment: What it the device you test on

Comment: @Dulanga AVD, API 28

Comment: Try getting the height of the navigation bar and setting paddingbottom of bottomsheet with layout params. 
to get height of nav bar -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264361/6341943

Comment: @panbacuh i'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution yet?