# How to center a ListPopupWindow/Other views on Android horizontally?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating a `ListPopupWindow` like this:

```
final ListPopupWindow insidelistPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(view.getContext());
insidelistPopupWindow.setContentWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popupNewWidth));
insidelistPopupWindow.setHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size300dp));
insidelistPopupWindow.setVerticalOffset(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size0dp));
insidelistPopupWindow.setHorizontalOffset(getPoupHorizontalOffset());
//set adapter...
insidelistPopupWindow.setAnchorView(view);
insidelistPopupWindow.show();
```

I tried to do simple math

```
public int getPoupHorizontalOffset() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    return getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popupNewWidth) - width/2;
}
```

to center it horizontally. It worked on my phone but not on others, so I suspect something is wrong about my asumptions. But I also suspect there's a better way of solving this.

How do I simply center something horizontally programatically?

**PS**: the same ListPopupWindow but with different number of elements is getting placed on different positions on screen. Why this happens?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer below,

I tried

```
listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(view);

        listPopupWindow.setContentWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popupNewWidth));
        listPopupWindow.setHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size250dp));
        listPopupWindow.setVerticalOffset(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size50dp));
        listPopupWindow.setHorizontalOffset(listPopupWindowWidth(view, listPopupWindow));
        listPopupWindow.setPromptPosition(ListPopupWindow.POSITION_PROMPT_ABOVE);
```

and did

```
int listPopupWindowWidth(View view, ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int horizontalOffset = (screenWidth / 2) - (getRelativeLeft(view) + listPopupWindow.getWidth() / 2);
        return horizontalOffset;
    }

private int getRelativeLeft(View view) {
        if (view.getParent() == view.getRootView()) {
            return view.getLeft();
        } else {
            return view.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) view.getParent());
        }
    }
```

but my popup is slightly to the left, not exactly centered. My view is in landscape mode, does it have anything to do with it? I tried changing width by height but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `ListPopupWindow` gets horizontally aligned with the left position of the anchor view. So, we should align its left side by calculating the difference of the current center from the screen center:

```
int screenWidth = getScreenSize().x;
if (isLandscape()) {
     screenWidth += getNavigationBarHeight();
}

int horizontalOffset = (screenWidth / 2) - (getRelativeLeft(view) + insidelistPopupWindow.getWidth() / 2);

insidelistPopupWindow.setHorizontalOffset(horizontalOffset);
```

`getRelativeLeft()` helps us to find the real left position of the anchor view regarding the screen (not its parent `ViewGroup`).

```
private int getRelativeLeft(View view) {
    if (view.getParent() == view.getRootView()) {
        return view.getLeft();
    } else {
        return view.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) view.getParent());
    }
}
```

And to get the screen size:

```
private Point getScreenSize() {
    Point point = new Point();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (wm.getDefaultDisplay() != null) {
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
    }
    return point;
}

private boolean isLandscape() {
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    return (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

In this way, it doesn't matter where is the anchor view horizontally and how it's wrapped in nested layouts, the `ListPopupWindow` always resides in the middle of the screen.

[image]
    [image]

Comment: thank you very much, but it didnt work, see me update. Do you think I did anything wrong?

Comment: It's weird! I'll check it and respond.

Comment: Is it possible to take a screenshot and share?

Comment: I have a theory: even though the "3 buttons bar (left home and ___)" are hidden, they're hidden through a script. Is it possible that since they're not trully hidden by layout, that actual width being calculated is up to where they begin? If so, is it possible to take their size into account?

Comment: I think indeed thats whats happening: https://imgur.com/a/SgoPrmg

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to say that when you told the device is landscape.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264361/1631967

Comment: I tried the function you linked like this: `int horizontalOffset = (screenWidth / 2) - (getRelativeLeft(view) + listPopupWindow.getWidth() / 2) - getHeightNavigationBar();` but now it appears too much to the left

Comment: tried returning the width instead of height too but it appeared very much to the left too