# Can I disable ActionBar's navigation Spinner?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What I want to achieve is disabling all items on ActionBar except one. I have a custom `ActionBar` with `Menu`,several `TextViews`, one `Button` and a `Spinner` from ListNavigation. 
Spinner is created because of `bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);` like this  :

```
    SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.action_bar_spinner, names);
    // "listener" for spinner
    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerAdapter, new OnNavigationListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
            // do some stuff

            return true;
        }
    });
```

I want to disable the `Spinner`, so that it is inactive, but still visible with last item selected before disabling it.In short I need something like `bar.getNavigationSpinner.setEnabled(false)` if it existed. Question is: Is there some kind of workaround ? If not, is there a way to disable whole `ActionBar`,but keep it visible ?

Note: I want to achieve it in a Fragment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to disable the `Spinner` used in list navigation in `ActionBar`. But is't not a straightforward solution, rather a hack. ActionBar doesn't provide a direct access to the `Spinner` view. Unfortunately the `Spinner` is created in a private code without any id.

So how to access the `Spinner` instance? One solution could be to access it via Java reflection API, but I wouldn't recommend that.

A better solution is to get the root view for the current `Activity`, traverse it's child views (action bar and all it's views are present in the view hierarchy) and find the proper `Spinner`. Since the `Spinner` in action bar is presumably the only one you haven't created yourself, you should be able to distinguish it from the others.

Getting the root `View` is described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity).

The traversal is rather simple, just bear in mind that if you are using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), you have to look for `IcsSpinner` instead of `Spinner` (`IcsSpinner` does not extend from `Spinner`).

```java
private View findActionBarSpinner() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    List<View> spinners = traverseViewChildren( (ViewGroup) rootView );
    return findListNavigationSpinner(spinners); // implement according to your layouts
}

private List<View> traverseViewChildren(ViewGroup parent) {
    List<View> spinners = new ArrayList<View>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof Spinner) {
            spinners.add( child );
        } else if (child instanceof IcsSpinner) { // add this if you are using ActionBarSherlock
            spinners.add( child );
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            spinners.addAll( traverseViewChildren( (ViewGroup) child ) );
        }
    }
    return spinners;
}
```

The function `findListNavigationSpinner` should be implemented in a way that you are able to distinguish the other spinners. If you are not using any `Spinner` (or any view derived from it), the returned list should contain just one item.

The code above describes how to get the `Spinner` in an `Activity`. Naturally, it is not a problem to disable the `Spinner` from within a `Fragment`. The fragment has a reference to it's activity, so the activity can expose the code to the fragment via some interface.

Comment: Thannks a lot. Works as expected. I wonder why there is no method to access this spinner directly.

Comment: That's hard to tell. It might have been intentional to disable some unwanted customizations. In any case there are some things in action bar that are rather poorly designed.

Comment: @Tomik please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034733/disable-onclick-actionbar-spinner-until-a-process-is-complete

Answer (score 1):

The above code does not work with **Action Bar compat (v7 support library)**. I needed to enable/disable the action bar spinner of my app (API 2.2) using this support library but I have noticed that the name of the class is `SpinnerICS` instead `Spinner`.

The full package name is

```
android.support.v7.internal.widget.SpinnerICS
```

Because of this class is not visible and can not be imported in my code, I can not use:

```
if (child instanceof SpinnerICS) ...
```

So finally I solved my issue using `getClass().getName`. Therefore the code for enabling/disabling the spinner using Action Bar compat support library (v7) will be:

```
private List<View> traverseViewChildren(ViewGroup parent) {
    List<View> spinners = new ArrayList<View>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        String className = child.getClass().getName();
        if (child instanceof Spinner || className.equals("android.support.v7.internal.widget.SpinnerICS")) {
            spinners.add( child );
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            spinners.addAll( traverseViewChildren( (ViewGroup) child ) );
        }
    }
    return spinners;
}
```

Also, I have modified my findListNavigationSpinner method to check if the spinners list has elements to prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Because I only have one spinner in my app (in the Action Bar compat), so my code is this (you should adapt it if you would have more than one spinner):

```
private View findListNavigationSpinner(List<View> spinners) {
    // We only have one spinner in the app
    View result = null;
    if (spinners != null && spinners.size() > 0) {
         result = spinners.get(0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified by noting that the ActionBar (and Spinner) is between the root view and the content (with id == android.R.id.content).  So you can implement a breadth-first search and return the first Spinner you find, no longer adding to the queue once you hit the view with id == android.R.id.content.

Or do the depth-first search, but stop recursing when you hit the view with id == android.R.id.content as the Spinner isn't contained in there.

So there's no need to maintain any list, just return the first Spinner found.