# Can't find action bar (Sherlock) inside root view

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, spinner, android-spinner

I'm trying to find my activity's Action Bar's spinner so I can selectively show and hide it (`setNavigationMode` does not work for my purposes). I tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353493/460847), but the Action Bar doesn't appear to be in my activity's (which is an extension of `SherlockFragmentActivity`) root view.

```
private View findActionBarSpinner() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    List<View> spinners = traverseViewChildren( (ViewGroup) rootView );
    return findListNavigationSpinner(spinners); // implement according to your layouts
}
```

All I get for rootView is a FrameLayout containing the RelativeLayout defined in my layout file (with only the elements within). I don't see anything that looks like an Action Bar or a spinner, and and sure enough traverseViewChildren (in the link above) returns an empty list.

I also tried, in the spirit of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488149/460847), `View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();`. The result was the same.

I'm making the call to `findActionBarSpinner` inside `onOptionsItemSelected`. (Though I can't access it, the action bar is fully visible and working properly at this point, so I doubt it's an issue of trying to access it at the wrong part of lifecycle.)

Any ideas?

Comment: I think thats because the ActionBarShelock is not attached to the content view (as much as I could quickly see in the source code)

Comment: OK, then should the code I linked just never work? Do you know if there's a way to attach ABS's Action Bar to the content view?

Comment: As I said I'm not sure, maybe someone can give more information, and confirm if it is attached or not.

Comment: OK, thanks for the starting point!