# getRootView() not working

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dip" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Now in my code I would like to change the window's background color, and I'm doing it like this:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
View root = listview.getRootView();
root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```

If I understood this correctly, this should change the background color of the listview's parent (in this case, the LinearLayout). However this is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean but "it is not working"? Does it throw an exception? If yes, what exception do you get?

Comment: It means that nothing happens, no exceptions are thrown and the background color is not changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused, getRootView() won't get you that LinearLayout, but the parent of that view. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity). You should use `listview.getParent()` instead; note that it needs to be casted.

Answer (score 1):

try to use [`getParent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29) in place of `getRootView()` to get the instance of the surrounding `LinearLayout`..