# Find root layout in activity

Tags: android, layout

Is there a dynamic way to get at the root layout (the one that is the parent to all the other Layouts) in the XML currently set to my Activity?

What I'm after is rather than giving my root layout an explicit id and finding it via findViewById, I'm hoping to get something along the lines of

pseudo code:

```
this.findTopLayout();
```

having already called `setContentView(R.layout.foo);`

I'm not seeing anything in the spec that would do the trick, am I just missing it, or is there no way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity

Comment: it would appear that that's exactly what I'm looking for... you should post it as an answer, and I'll give you the green checkmark (and thanks very much)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You try out this way to get the root layout:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

OR

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

Comment: Both don't work in my Samsung Note9 in 2020.

Answer (score 4):

Note that apart from the method described by Grishu, you can also use the method [getParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29) on **any** view (this includes buttons, imageviews, layouts, etc) to get the parent of that view (the parent returned might also have a parent). Hence, an alternative method would be to loop on getParent from a particular view until getParent returns null. At that point, you would have found the root view of your content view.

Comment: yeah, that's useful in the other direction, but I am hoping (and the comments appear to give that exact answer) to avoid knowing anything about the layout specifically and to just walk my way down into it from the top.

Comment: you don't need to know anything about the layout or view even when calling getParent.

Comment: no, but I'd need to know the id of the child to get at IT first, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: i see your point- yes, you would need to have the child object in order to call getParent on it.