# basic canvas usage android

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I'm just starting out with Android (bought a book that will hopefully clear up most of these fundamental questions, but that's only going to arrive in a few weeks). I'm trying to make a Canvas that takes up part of an activity window (otherwise blank). All I want to do is play around with this and see how the lower level drawing pixels and stuff works. Later I want to see if i can make a small plotting program.

Basically, I'm confused on how to create a canvas onto the activity and draw onto that. I've tried to piece together something  workable, which compiles without errors but doesn't do what its supposed to do. Here's my attempt:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Graph extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);

    View curView = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0); //should return a view without top bar...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);
    canvas.save();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setColor(0xFF0000FF); //blue hopefully
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 5, paint);
    curView.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.graph, menu);
    return true;
    }

}
```

The activity_graph.xml is just as basic as it gets:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Graph" >
```

I'd be glad for any corrections to my code as well, along with corrected code for what I'm trying to do. I feel like I'm missing something major here, but just can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class which extends the View and override its onDraw() method. You can also override onSizeChanged() to find out the size of a view.

The good book which describes the basics of Canvas programming is shown below:[http://www.amazon.com/Android-Graphics-Canvas-API-ebook/dp/B00DKIAVK8/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1374432627&sr=1-1&keywords=android+2d+graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DKIAVK8)

"Android 2D Graphics programming with Canvas API" by Yevgen Karpenko.
It has a lot of simple examples.