# How to get a View of a Fragment having a reference to it?

Tags: android

I have a reference to one of my `Fragment`s obtained by:

```
Fragment fragmentByTag = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tabName);
```

Now I need to get it's `View`, which was setup on its `onCreateView()` method. I tried:

```
View view = fragmentByTag.getView();
```

but the `view` is always `null`.

Meaning I have a reference to a `Fragment` which was correctly instantiated and shown, no doubts. Having a reference to it I need to get a `layout` associated with it.

Comment: Are you accessing it at the right time? Is it possible that you are querying the property before the onCreateView method has returned?

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity

Comment: @Ameen, do you mean this should work? I'll check out if I call it at the right time.

Comment: @siik, yes absolutely, this code should work (assuming it's accessed at the right time :))

Comment: @Ameen, please answer then so I can boost your rating a bit :)

Comment: @siik, hahah, sounds good to me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. You'll have to ensure though that you are accessing the `getView` method after the `onCreateView` method of the `Fragment` has returned.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the only reason it is null is because I was accessing it before the `onCreateView()` was finished, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few reasons as to why it is null. I had a similar problem when the view had been destroyed and I was trying to reference it. Are you sure it is on top and accessible/visible?

Can we some more code as to where you are calling this? Have you provided it a layout (i.e. inflated it), and gone through the correct sequence of onAttach(...), onCreate(...), onCreateView(...) and onActivityCreated(...). See the link below for information on that. Showing us these methods may help us solve your problem.

[Fragment Creation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)