# Inflating Views problems. Trying to add a view to a layout. ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, view

Ok I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. After looking up many directions and what not I came up with this snippet but I am not sure why it doesn't work. An explanation and help would be greatly appreciated. LogCat logs included.

activity_camera.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:text="menu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Take pic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the snippet that gives me an error

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE); mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_camera, null);
        mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        RL.addView(mTextureView);
        setContentView(RL);
```

logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  784): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1723)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1670)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:382)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:403)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(  784):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your activity_camera.xml

Comment: why do you have this duplicated: `mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE); mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);` ?

Comment: hah, i wouldn't even notice that, accident when moving it from one activity to another.

Comment: That fine , it does not create any problem.

Comment: @Brontok  posted the xml

Comment: you are trying to case a framelayout to a relative layout as per the logcat :O

Comment: You are trying to cast framelayout to relative layout as it depicts from the error.Type cast it properly

Comment: Hey, first comment this 3 lines  mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        RL.addView(mTextureView); And try ? and let me know what log cat says? i will give you solution for your problem. please do it first

Comment: @BrijeshPatel Everything works fine then, but my TextureView obviously is not being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you `onCreate` code to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);

    RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    RL.addView(mTextureView);
}
```

You need to call `super.onCreate` first. Then `setContentView` to your layout (which is the id = name of your file, not your relative layout). Then you can find your relative layout inside.

Comment: Nowhere in my code, all in the android libraries. but im deducing it is this: `RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_layout);`

Comment: Updated my answer, try again.

Comment: `android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout` Same thing. WHERE IS THIS FRAMELAYOUT

Comment: No idea! Try different answers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity

Answer (score 1):

Clean/Rebuild your project , it does not have any error. If problem still persists delete your R.java and build project again.

Comment: Whats is requirement exactly, May be i will modify your code and help you somehow.

Comment: My TextureView provides me with camera preview, Since I have it defined this way I need my buttons there to take the picture or go to menu which are defined in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest it would be useful if you posted the xml layout that you are using.
But the most likely solution seems that the top level element in the xml layout is NOT a RelativeLayout; thus the type cast (correctly) fails.

You don;t seem to require any functionality of the relative layout so I think you should cast to a more generic class (perhaps FrameLayout?). This would make you code more resilient to changes in the layout format files.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All! So I fixed this this way in my activity_camera.xml i Changed from RelativeLayout to FrameLayout. So far so good. but thanks @Szymon His answer helped mine work.

Answer (score -1):

open your xml file named activity_camera and make sure the layout is RelativeLayout. if not,you should change the layout in the xml file, or change this line RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_camera, null);RelativeLayout change to FrameLayout.