# Two or more layouts on the screen

Tags: android

I have some problem.
I try to show on the screen background with picture on it. My background is in the

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_nebo" />
```

end i show it on the screen

```
setContentView(R.layout.background);
```

But my secon picture, that i need to shown is in class extends SurfaceView

```
  public class GameView extends SurfaceView 
    {
        /**Загружаемая картинка*/
        private Bitmap bmp;

    /**Наше поле рисования*/
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    //конструктор
    public GameView(Context context) 
    {
          super(context);
          holder = getHolder();
          holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() 
          {
                 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
                 {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
                 {
                        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                        onDraw(canvas);
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
                 {
                 }
          });
          bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.soldat);
    }

    //Рисуем нашу картинку на черном фоне
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
          canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
          canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);
    }
}
```

and I try to put it on the screen by

```
setContentView( new GameView(this));
```

but I but I already have `setContentView` method 
How I can draw this two picture, one from xml file and another from class `setContentView` in simultaneously?

Comment: Why the second call to `setContentView()`? What do you want to change? Only the background? Or also the layout elements?

Comment: I try to do simple game. And I need to show background with small picture on it. And this picture in future will move and something else

Comment: If you only want a background, in your `Activity`'s XML file, use the `android:background="@drawable/ic_nebo"` attribute instead of using an `ImageView`.

Comment: I need background WITH picture on it simultaneously.

Comment: Get the root `View` as shown in:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity. Then use `View.setBackgroundResource()` or similar methods from `View`.

Comment: Sure, posting this as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the root `View` as shown in this post: [Get root view from current activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity). Then use `View.setBackgroundResource()` or similar methods from the obtained `View`