# Google Game Play Service Achievement does not pop up

Tags: android, google-play-games, achievements

I try to implement Game Play Service Achievement in my game, but when achievement is unlocked, it does not pops up (show that achievement is unlocked) but when I open list of all achievements it shows that is unlocked. So my problem is, how to pops up achievement when it's unlocked ?

**MainActivity.class**

```
 public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  private void callGooglePlay(){  
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();
    }
```

**PlayActivity.class**

```
 Games.Achievements.unlock(MainMenu.mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.e));
```

Comment: are you running it on the UIThread?

Comment: Also, the pop-up only appears the first time you unlock it, it is cloud based, you need to reset it on the Play Games Console server side.

Comment: Yes, it is running on UIThread.
It doesn't appear at all even if first time unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `getAchievementsIntent()` to create the default achievements UI, and then call the `startActivityForResult`

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

More information about [displaying achievements](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements#displaying_achievements) can be found on the documentation.

If you need a notification that's specific to the achievement being unlocked, you can try to use [`setViewForPopups`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html#setViewForPopups(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, android.view.View)) as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705483/no-pop-up-is-displayed-when-calling-games-achievements-unlock).