# Google Play Game Services + Emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, bluestacks

I am unable to connect to Google Play Game Services in a native emulator, however, the same apk works in Bluestacks.

So far the app requests a list of the user's achievements via [Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements#getAchievementsIntent(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)). These achievements are successfully displayed in Bluestacks, however, the native emulator screen remains blank.

To be honest, it came as a surprise when Bluestacks displayed the user's achievements (as shown below) as I had not implemented any presentation logic.

[image: app running in Bluestacks]

I am building dependencies with Google Play Services 9.6.1:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.6.1'
```

Emulator is running a system image with API 24 + Google APIs

I am using an automanaged instance of GoogleApiClient which attempts to connect but then fails. I have tried numerous fixes to no avail.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,
                    this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "resultCode = " + resultCode);
    if (resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("onConnected", "onConnected");
    startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), MY_REQ_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d("onConnectionFailed", "onConnectionFailed");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Result in Android Monitor:

```
    Connected to process 7907 on device Nexus_5X_API_24_GApps [emulator-5554]
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/goc.dma.cprach.gameofchairs-1/lib/x86
W/PopupManager: You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view. Note that this may not work as expected in multi-screen environments
D/AutoManageHelper: starting AutoManage for client 0 false false
D/onStart: onStart
D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqa$zza@e9fa141}

                    [ 10-20 03:00:11.990  1490: 1511 D/         ]
                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8c3f9680, tid 1511
W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

                  [ 10-20 03:00:12.089  7907: 7907 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa438dac0, tid 7907
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/onConnectionFailed: onConnectionFailed
D/AutoManageHelper: beginFailureResolution for ConnectionResult{statusCode=RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{20c0bc3: android.os.BinderProxy@6889c40}, message=null}
D/onActivityResult: resultCode = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but I noticed in your error log that it says:

```
"You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups."
```

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705483/no-pop-up-is-displayed-when-calling-games-achievements-unlock) which suggests:

**use setViewForPopUps method**

```
 Games.setViewForPopups(getApiClient(), getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

Another way to do this is to:

**define setViewForPopups in your mGoogleApiClient object.**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
            .build();
```

Looking at your code, it seems you haven't added this. Here's additional reading on [setViewForPopups method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games#setViewForPopups(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.view.View)).