# How to show Snackbar when Activity starts?

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar

I want to show android `Snackbar` `(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar)` when the activity starts just like we show a `Toast`.

But the problem is we have to specify the parent layout when creating `Snackbar` like this:

```
Snackbar.make(parentlayout, "This is main activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            })
            .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light ))
            .show();
```

How to give parent layout when we show `Snackbar` at the start of the activity without any click events (If it was a click event we could've easily pass the parent view)?

Comment: Written an article to http://onetouchcode.com/2016/12/24/use-snackbar-android-apps/ , This will be helpful to know more details of Snackbar

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Just point to any `View` inside the `Activity's` XML. You can give an id to the root viewGroup, for example, and use:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
   setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
   View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
   Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "This is main activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG) 
        .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {

            } 
        }) 
        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light ))
        .show(); 
   //Other stuff in OnCreate();
}
```

Comment: For the root view, you can also generally use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` as indicated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4488149/1518546

Comment: View parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_view); throws nullpointer exception in 5.0 or lower version. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: @AnandSavjani The code is working perfectly  with me for 5.0 and below 5.0, there must be some error in your layout(root_view). If you are using fragment you should write rootview.findViewById(R.id.your_parent_view); And also dont give same id as layout name.

Comment: I believe it throws NullpointerException if you are not using CoordinatorLayout as the root.

Comment: Don't forget to include the support design library : 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'

Comment: 'getColor()' deprecated in api 23. Use ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name) instead.

Answer (score 53):

I have had trouble myself displaying Snackbar until now.
Here is the simplest way to display a Snackbar. To display it as your Main Activity Starts, just put these two lines inside your `OnCreate()`

```
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Welcome To Main Activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbar.show();
```

P.S. Just make sure you have imported the Android Design Support.(As mentioned in the question).

**For Kotlin,**

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 11):

> Try this

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Got the Result", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Submit", mOnClickListener)
                        .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                        .show();
```

Answer (score 6):

A utils function for show snack bar

```
fun showSnackBar(activity: Activity, message: String, action: String? = null,
    actionListener: View.OnClickListener? = null, duration: Int = Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    val snackBar = Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, duration)
        .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CC000000")) // todo update your color
        .setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    if (action != null && actionListener!=null) {
        snackBar.setAction(action, actionListener)
    }
    snackBar.show()
}
```

Example using in Activity

```
  showSnackBar(this, "No internet")
  showSnackBar(this, "No internet", duration = Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  showSnackBar(activity, "No internet", "OK", View.OnClickListener { 
       // handle click 
  })
```

Example using in Fragment

```
  showSnackBar(getActivity(), "No internet")
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 4):

> call this method in onCreate

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(
                    (((Activity) context).findViewById(android.R.id.content)),
                    message + "", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
snack.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);//change Duration as you need
            //snack.setAction(actionButton, new View.OnClickListener());//add your own listener
            View view = snack.getView();
            TextView tv = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);//change textColor

            TextView tvAction = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action);
            tvAction.setTextSize(16);
            tvAction.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            snack.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done simply by using the following codes inside onCreate. By using android's default layout

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Your Message",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: on android version 5.x - suddenly `getWindow().getDecorView()` return ALL screen, include 'bottom buttons' (such home, back etc). So my snack was showing down to this buttons, not in app

Comment: check the updated answer. It will solve your problem. Use android's default layout

Comment: yes, when I changed from `window` to `android.R.id.content` all start work. So I wrote my comment to solve someones else issue with it in future)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to show some text:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "<text>", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// or
Snackbar.make(view, "<text>", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and to show text with a button:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "<text>", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("<button_text>", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    // operation to perform when the button is clicked
            } 
        }).show();
```

Comment: an Activity doesn't have a "view' so this doesn't work.

Comment: you can still use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` or `requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library. This is a wrapper for android default snackbar. https://github.com/ChathuraHettiarachchi/CSnackBar

```
Snackbar.with(this,null)
    .type(Type.SUCCESS)
    .message("Profile updated successfully!")
    .duration(Duration.SHORT)
    .show();
```

This contains multiple types of snackbar and even a customview intergrated snackbar

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a super class for all your activities and find the view once in the parent activity.

for example

AppActivity.java :

```
public class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected View content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        changeLanguage("fa");
        content = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}
```

and your snacks would look like this in every activity in your app:

```
Snackbar.make(content, "hello every body", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It is better for performance you have to find the view once for every activity.

Answer (score 0):

For those developers who use `data binding` in their project.

```
Snackbar.make(binding.getRoot(), "This is your text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("CLOSE", view -> {
                            //close
                        })
                        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light ))
                        .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Snackbar in Activity, use this code

```
View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

Snackbar.make(view, "Hello, world!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Hello there! I suggest formatting your code. If you do not know how to, please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Have a nice day!