# Checking/Storing inputs from EditTexts(Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to learn android in java but I m stuck. Here is my method to get values from EditText fields.

```
public void sendFeedback(View button) { 


      System.out.println("Do not fail");
           final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
           String name = nameField.getText().toString();
           final EditText numberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Cost);
           String test=numberField.getText().toString();
           Integer x = Integer.parseInt(test.trim());
           System.out.println(x);
           System.out.println(name);
         }
```

This is the xml for button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:onClick="sendFeedback"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</Button>
```

What I want to do is following. If someone leaves EditText Null or  enters a non-integer value to numberfield I want to DISPLAY that in android but System.out.println() does not display anything. If the previous case does not happen I want to save the variables to a local database. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void sendFeedback(View button) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Do not fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    if(nameField != null) {
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Namefield is empty!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    final EditText numberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Cost);
    if(numberField != null) {
        String test = numberField.getText().toString();
        if(!test.isEmpty()) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(test.trim());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cost: " + x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't entered a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This crashes the program. Probably because of trying to use a null value. But it works correctly when I enter values to inputs. What I want is to notify user when they try to submit while form is empty

Comment: I edited the code in my answer, you should get notified if no text is entered in either field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that message to the user you can use  `Toast` or `Snackbar`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` logs the message to the `console`. So, you cannot use it to display error in the `UI`. To show error in `Android` you should use these :

- use [editText.setError()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225365/show-error-on-the-tip-of-the-edit-text-android);
- [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)

  - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978457/how-to-show-snackbar-when-activity-starts)  for how to display a Snackbar in Android
- [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

  - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android) for how to display a Toast in Android

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println() prints to the console. Try using Toast to notify the user invalid input