# How to add a snackbar in the Next activity?

Tags: android

I have a button in an activity,`on click` of that button I want to show the `Snack bar` in my next activity.

I have tried adding it but the snackbar view lies in the same activity.

What should i do?

Comment: for that the next activity must be visible . . .that is why snackbar is visible in same activity

Comment: Put snackBar on NextActivity onCreate() , go with this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978457/how-to-show-snackbar-when-activity-starts

Comment: Pass one value with intent in next activity check for that value in next activity on create. and in condition show the snack bar.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the message to display in `SnackBar` in the `Intent` you use to start the next `Activity`. Then, when the new `Activity` start, you could get the message from the `Intent` and display it in a `SnackBar` from a `View` in that `Activity`.

Comment: thanks that worked Out for me..

Answer (score 0):

Pass some parameter with intent to **NextActivity** on your button click in **ActivityOne**. In **onCreate**  method of **NextActivity** check the paramter and if it verifies that the launch event was fired from that button click in **ActivityOne**, Show the SnackBar.