# Adding elements from a Object

Tags: android

How can I add a `View` in my `Activity` from a instantiated object?

I have this class:

```
   public class Object {
       public Object (Context context) {
         this.context = context
       }
       public void my_method() {
          //Add something in my view
       }
    }
```

and my `mainactivity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Object obj = new Object(this);
//when i call this method \/ i wanted to add anything in my view 
                obj.my_method();
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Why have you named your class Object ?! You are shadowing `java.lang.Object`...

Answer (score 1):

Use this methodology to get the activity main view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488149/785121

Then pass it to your method: obj.my_method(view)

Answer (score -1):

You should start by specifying the component where your object will put the view. For example, add a `LinearLayout` to your activity_main.xml and find a reference to it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
```

Once you have that reference, pass it as a constructor argument to your Object, or as an argument to `my_method()`. For example:

```
Object obj = new Object(this, layout);
```

or

```
obj.my_method(layout);
```

Finally, make your method create the views and add it to the container:

```
public void my_method() {
    layout.addView(...);
}
```