# getCurrentFocus() returns null

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I'm trying to display a **Snackbar** in the screen with some File data that I retrieve in the `onActivityResult()` method after taking a photo.

The thing is that the **View** that is passed to the Snackbar returns null and I cannot display it.

This is the code of the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);

    if (this.getCurrentFocus() != null)
      Snackbar.make(this.getCurrentFocus(), f.length() / (1024 * 1024) + " MB, " + f.getPath(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
  }
}
```

Any idea why this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is because when you calling another Activity, the current focus is lost in the caller Activity so it's set to null.

As the [documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getCurrentFocus()):

> View getCurrentFocus ()
>
> Return the view in this Window **`that currently has focus`**, or null if
>   there are none. Note that this does not look in any containing Window.

You can use the root view of your activity for the **Snackbar**:

```
// Get the root current view.
View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Snackbar.make(view, f.length() / (1024 * 1024) + " MB, " + f.getPath(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Please be noted that

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

may be behind navigation bar (with back button etc.) on some devices (but it seems on most devices it is not).
As in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488149/4758255 says.

you can use:

```
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

But better just set id to this view in your xml layout and use this id instead.

Or as op has said, we can use:

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for the late response, I found another solution for this.                                                                                         `View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();` This way I obtain the root view of the Activity and pass it as the first parameter in the `Snackbar.make()` method

Comment: No problem. I've integrated your solution to my answer. In case someone else stumbles upon the same problem.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `getCurrentFocus()` for view in an activity. you will almost always get a view. It is nullable though