# Adding view programmatically to a FragmentActivity dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to add a Image icon to be added on top of `rootView` in `FragmentActivity`.

I tried doing this:

```
 ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            myView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.iconimage, null);
            rootLayout.addView(myView );
            rootLayout.invalidate();
```

But realised that this only works for `AppCompatActivity`, and doesn't work for `FragmentActivity`. As my image cannot be seen.

How can i add Views to Classes that `extends FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Please provide your xml layout file.

Comment: hi @GeniusQ, I tried putting simple xml layout. Even if it's just one linearlayout with match_parent for width and height it won't display the image icon.

Comment: Did you LinearLayout have id? I saw you find your rootView with the id come from android.R.id, not R.id.

Comment: yes, but `android.R.id.content` directly references the root view of your activity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity. I don't want to rely on ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` is a subclass of `FragmentActivity` so all features of `FragmentActivity` will be available in `AppCompatActivity`.

So making your activity extend `AppCompatActivity` should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't find a way to addView to FragmentActivity so i have no choice but to change it to AppCompactActivity

Comment: Glad I could help. :)