# Snackbar not showing, the app crashes every time I open it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, findviewbyid, android-snackbar

I tried to resolve this error but I wasn't successful with it.
When is open the application the app crashes and stops instantly.
Is there something am not doing right?

```java
    private void popupSnackBarForCompleteUpdate() {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "New app is ready!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)

        .setAction("Install", view -> {
            if (appUpdateManager != null) {
                appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
            }
        })
        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.installColor))
        .show();
    }
```

**Throws the following error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
        at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:158)
```

I had the below code before switching to `android.R.id.content`

```java
    private void popupSnackBarForCompleteUpdate() {
        Snackbar snackbar =
                Snackbar.make((CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.snackbar_layout), "New app is ready!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

        snackbar.setAction("Install", view -> {
            if (appUpdateManager != null) {
                appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
            }
        });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.installColor));
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

Comment: is the view `android.R.id.content` that you made it on, on the actual page? Is it also the root view?

Comment: No @IAmGroot. This what is had initially before `android.R.id.content` ` Snackbar snackbar =
                Snackbar.make((CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content), "New app is ready!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

        snackbar.setAction("Install", view -> {
            if (appUpdateManager != null) {
                appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
            }
        });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.installColor));
        snackbar.show();
    }
`

Comment: I had this on my root view : ```private void popupSnackBarForCompleteUpdate() {
        Snackbar snackbar =
                Snackbar.make((CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.snackbar_layout), "New app is ready!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

        snackbar.setAction("Install", view -> {
            if (appUpdateManager != null) {
                appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
            }
        });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.installColor));
        snackbar.show();
    } ```

Comment: @joseph try adding `getRootView()` after your find view by id `android.R.id.content`

Comment: @joseph I have added this as an answer please accept and do a upvote if it did help you so that other users can find it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to fetch the rootview for your activity then you should use :- `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()`. (You are missing `getRootView()` here).

Or else you can also use `requireView().rootView` and it will return you root view of your fragment and have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity) answer as well to get rootview from your activity.