# How to offset a centered item inside a view by the height of the header

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-view

I'm working with a simple Android view (2 buttons). I've centered the buttons vertically but I noticed they are a little further down than directly center.

From what I can tell they are being centered using the space left over (after the header is put into the view). What I would prefer is that the header is not part of the view or that I could offset the centering by a specific dip (so it looks center instead of offset looking)

Anyone know if this is truly my issue or if you can offset a centered item?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loadViewBtn"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="View"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
    </Button>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/loadUploadBtn"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="Upload"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loadViewBtn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Define "header" - I cannot see this in your XML. Is this the title bar of the activity you are referring to (which you can turn off) OR is it a header defined somewhere else in your XML? IF you are talking about the title bar then refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Comment: I suppose I'm talking about the default title bar that's shown unless you do what @Edwin mentioned below

Answer (score 1):

You could add a linearlayout on the bottom that is the same size as the header -- [Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)

Or remove the header, see http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-make-an-activity-fullscreen

Comment: Agree with @Graham that you should probably remove title bar in the layout xml

Answer (score 1):

My answer based upon comments is to hide the title bar, which is the same answers written in this Stackoverflow question [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

My usual method to do this is either in the custom theme declaration OR manifest. I personally believe this is a better separation of concerns, as doing things to the UI in code that could be done within a defined theme just seems neater - especially if it has to be replicated in other activities.

Manifest Example

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Theme Declaration Example

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```