# Fallacious event.getY() of MapView in APIs 14+

Tags: android, android-mapview, projection, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

App is to create a mark on the google map. It creates a mark in the right place with the APIs up to 13.

```
GeoPoint longpressLocation = getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(),
(int)event.getY());
```

But in 14+ it increases event.getY by roughly 40 pixels.
It's also mentioned in manifest to hide the title bar:

```
<activity android:name=".Travelalarm" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Is there any good-looking decision except for simply decreasing it by that number of pixels with `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13`?

Answer (score 0):

i have about 58 pixels with sdk 13 and about 110 pixel with sdk 14 only with event.getY();

Comment: With the ActionBar I currently have to use `getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY() - statusBarHeight - actionBarHeight);`

Comment: Where `statusBarHeight` and `actionBarHeight` can easily be attained by the recipe from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3410200/986216 (TitleBarHeight = actionBarHeight in this case)