# Whats the appropriate way to work with phone screen size?

Tags: android, screen-size

The following code returns the screen size:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

I'm using RelativeLayout to arrange components inside. For some reason when I divide width between components (say `width*30/100` and `width*70/100`) I get some screen space left out. And also about the height how can I get height of status bar and title bar does it vary among phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android) would help you. It states the difference in the sizes of status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is all in [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Quick summary: Android rounds up/down these values based on the nearest supported density/size ratio. You may not get the exact measurements you want, depending on your phone.

Also, Display is deprecated - use [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)