# How to detect position of notifications area?

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect programmatically whether the notification area is located at the top  of the screen or in the bottom right corner (like on most tablets) ?

Comment: This is a good question, but why? What evil intentions do you have in mind with this knowledge? :-p

Comment: Note: to complicate things a bit Nexus 7 is a tablet and has its notifications along the top, rather than at the bottom right.

Comment: @FoamyGuy you're right, I meant "on most tablets". I guess. :)

Comment: (*not sure if this will help but worth a shot*) Try some of the techniques in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android you might be able to glean where the notifications go based on the fact that the bottom bar is taller than the top bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications are always shown in a 25dp-tall status bar at the top of the display, *except* for `sw600` devices (that is, the smallest width in any orientation is 600dp; see [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) for more info) on API levels 11 (Honeycomb) through 16 (Jelly Bean pre-MR1). On those devices there is a 48dp-tall "combined system bar" at the bottom of the display.

The easiest way to check for this is via qualified resources; that is, put your top-status-bar-assuming layout in `layout/foo.xml`, but then have a bottom-system-bar version in `layout-sw600dp/foo.xml`. Finally, since these large devices now use the top status bar as of Android 4.2 (API 17) you'll need to switch back to the top-status-bar version in `layout-sw600dp-v17/foo.xml`.

If you just want a boolean value that will tell you whether the status bar is at the top, replace `layout` in the above example with `values`, and place a `<bool>` into `foo.xml` that is true except in the `values-sw600dp` case.