# How can an app detect the status bar color (Android 5.0 Lollipop)?

Tags: android, colors, window, statusbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I've been toying around with the Android 5.0 Lollipop APIs, when I came across [`Window#getStatusBarColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getStatusBarColor%28%29). However, this requires an instance of `Window` say from an `Activity`, so it can't be used in a background service. Is there a way for an app to detect the status bar color on Android 5.0?

**Update**:

As Nikola Despotoski mentioned, there is the [`createScreenCaptureIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent()) method which could do the trick by "screen recording," and just checking the status bar region.
As it turns out, the return value of this method if passed to `startActivityForResult`. The initial request is meant to be called from an Activity.
Even if the result was saved and passed to a Service, there would need to be some complex pattern to re-ask for permission every time it was needed. There also doesn't seem to be a synchronous way to obtain a Bitmap. In the background, this means always processing screen changes just to obtain a single pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

You can make use of new Lolipop screen capture API. Using [createScreenCaptureIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent()) and `MediaProjectionManager` to retrieve the `Bitmap`.

Once you have the bitmap, try to cut (decode) the Bitmap from top=0 to bottom=[status_bar_height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android). Pass the cut `Bitmap` to `Palette` and retrieve the color using `getRGB()` method.

Comment: I thought about this, but it seemed excessively complicated and expensive in terms of CPU (especially in the case of fast app switching).