# set navigation drawer on actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have created a navigation drawer.I want to show the drawer below the status bar .Its works fine as what i'm expected.But the drawer open above the status bar on version 5 and above.I want set the drawer as like the second image.How to set the navigation drawer on the action(i.e) below status bar for all version.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="close"
   >

    <include
        layout="@layout/emp_app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/menubg"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/emp_header"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_emp_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`
[image: drawer opens above action bar in versaion 5+ mobiles]

[image: image2]

[image]

Comment: is this you want ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36587544/5188159

Comment: no not like that i need to open the drawer below the status bar.your example like the drawers opens below actionbar

Comment: ah got it let me see mm

Comment: this should do the job -- >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271251/put-navigation-drawer-under-status-bar

Comment: Did you know that answer

Comment: In your `NavigationView` try adding this `android:layout_marginTop="56dp"`

Comment: If i set margin means its works on above version 5 but the layout moves down below version 5 @PrasadPawar

Comment: @Abserve Tech - It's working for me on 4.4.4, 5.0 and 6.0 as well! Are you sure about that?

Comment: ya i'm sure i told after i had tested your answer @PrasadPawar

Comment: in that case, you can add the margin via code. Here's a link for status bar height. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29696508/4511297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `DrawerLayout` or making it false like `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`, probably this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/emp_app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/menubg"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/emp_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_emp_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to find the height of the statusbar and offset it.

```
private NavigationView mNavView;
private View mHeaderView;
//...
mNavView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
//...
mHeaderView = mNavView.getHeaderView(0);
//...
LinearLayout mHeaderLayout = (LinearLayout) HeaderView.findViewById(R.id.headerLayout);
//..
mHeaderLayout.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
```

The function for getting statusbar height is:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Ps. The find statusbar height I got it somewhere else long time ago...

Comment: Your answer working good but one thing is if i set padding for headerlayout means some of the text is move inside.so that i have set padding for mNavView.

Comment: After that  it works fine as what i'm expected but the gray color is shown in top of the status bar.Is there any possibilty for setting the margins dynamically in mNavView instead of padding

Comment: I think if you shift the margin, it will expose the background which is the grey color you saw. So I think padding is better than margin.

By the way, what do you mean by some of the text is moved inside ?

Comment: If you look closely, I shifted the layout not the header itself nor the navigation view. I think you can try to wrap everything inside one layout and then top padding that layout.

Comment: see that posted image it contain username and email id.That emailid get move i inside the layout

Comment: Can you include your header .xml ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128064/discussion-between-abserve-tech-and-aung).

Answer (score 0):

put the  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `emp_header` which you mention in `app:headerLayout="@layout/emp_header"`