# Android transparent status bar and actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, android-statusbar

I've done a few researches on this topic and I couldn't find a complete solution  so, step by step and with some trial and error, I finally find out how can we achieve these results: having a transparent or coloured `Actionbar` and `Statusbar`. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

I'm developing an app that needs to look similar in all devices with >= API14 when it comes to actionbar and statusbar customization. I've finally found a solution and since it took a bit of my time I'll share it to save some of yours.
We start by using an appcompat-21 dependency.

**Transparent Actionbar**:

**values/styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_yellow</item>
</style>
```

**values-v21/styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_yellow</item>
</style>
```

Now you can use these themes in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to specify which activities will have a transparent or colored `ActionBar`:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".MyTransparentActionbarActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".MyColoredActionbarActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"/>
```

[image] [image]
[image] [image]
[image]

Note: in API>=21 to get the `Actionbar` transparent you need to get the `Statusbar` transparent too, otherwise will not respect your colour styles and will stay light-grey.

**Transparent Statusbar (only works with API>=19)**:

This one it's pretty simple just use the following code:

```
protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
        if (makeTranslucent) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }
```

But you'll notice a funky result:
[image]

This happens because when the `Statusbar` is transparent the layout will use its height. To prevent this we just need to:

**SOLUTION ONE:**
Add this line `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your layout view container of whatever you want to be placed bellow the Actionbar:

```
    ...
        <LinearLayout
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    ...
```

**SOLUTION TWO:**
Add a few lines to our previous method:

```
protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
        View v = findViewById(R.id.bellow_actionbar);
        if (v != null) {
            int paddingTop = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT ? MyScreenUtils.getStatusBarHeight(this) : 0;
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
            paddingTop += TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            v.setPadding(0, makeTranslucent ? paddingTop : 0, 0, 0);
        }
        
        if (makeTranslucent) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }
```

Where `R.id.bellow_actionbar` will be the layout container view id of whatever we want to be placed bellow the `Actionbar`:

```
...
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bellow_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

[image]

So this is it, it think I'm not forgetting something.
In this example I didn't use a `Toolbar` but I think it'll have the same result. This is how I customize my `Actionbar`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vg = getActionBarView();
        getWindow().requestFeature(vg != null ? Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR : Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentView());
        
        if (vg != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(vg, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        }
        setStatusBarTranslucent(true);
    }
```

Note: this is an `abstract class` that extends `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: You should really use [android:fitsSystemWindows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) if you want to ensure your View is not underneath the transparent status bar.

Comment: That's totally correct, I was reviewing my code and I'm using this too. Don't know I missed it in this example. I'll update it, thanks!

Comment: You are missing `MyScreenUtils.getStatusBarHeight(this)`  here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3410200/1307690

Comment: is there a way to make it translucent and not completly transparent? I am on api 23

Comment: To get Transparent StatusBar Works I needed to add `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`  Flag, putting the code `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);` after that `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);`

Comment: I believe this worked before, but in API 23 it doesn't work anymore. The status bar will be just grey instead of transparent

Comment: Add FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS here worked as mentioned by @EduardoE.R.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using CoordinatorLayout as your layout Just replace/wrap it with another layout (in my case, I used ConstraintLayout) then it will work.

Comment: If you use FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, adjustPan and adjustResize are disabled for soft keyboard. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @vanste25 did you find please some solution?

Answer (score 2):

It supports after KITKAT. Just add following code inside onCreate method of your Activity. No need any modifications to Manifest file.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
                w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            }
```

Comment: This makes the navigation bar also transparent

Comment: This breaks scrolling when keyboard is open

Answer (score -1):

Just add these lines of code to your activity/fragment java file:

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
);
```

Comment: This breaks scrolling when keyboard is open