# How to bring ImageView under the transparent Status Bar

Tags: android, xml, statusbar, transparent, android-framelayout

In the images below,I am trying to bring the ImageView under the StatusBar. But its not happening.

[Image Screenshot on Android API 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxgrX.png)

[Image Screenshot on Android API 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnZ4p.png)

**I went on [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar) (this question) and tried to implement the same but its not working.**

The **xml layout of the activity** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/category_layout_top"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:id="@+id/category_Image_View"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/def_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />




</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:id="@+id/category_linearlayout">
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:singleLine="true"
android:id="@+id/category_textView"
/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I tried the below code in the **onCreate()** method also

```
 setStatusBarTranslucent(true);



protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
    if (makeTranslucent) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    } else {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
}
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

**style-v21.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**AppTheme is the style used in the activity.**

**EDIT 1**

**I used a  color in the background of FrameLayout to check whether it was under the status bar or not. And it is not.**

So the problem is not with Layout, I guess.

**EDIT 2**
this is the desired result 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In style-v21 you are overriding the style AppTheme.NoActionBar, but you said the style you use in your activity is the AppTheme style.

You need to override the AppTheme layout in style-v21 or define AppTheme.NoActionBar in you activity.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks :) I noticed it now. I will do that. But it won't have effect on the problem for pre lollipop versions..

Comment: I believe that the problem is with scaling. Try to add scaleType="centerCrop" or "fitXY" to your imageView

Comment: Nope,its the same. Please check the Edit too.

Comment: The problem is not with action bar, is with the imageView. set the width/height to match parent and apply the scaleTypes that I said and it will work.

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: There are any changes from the print screen you posted?

Comment: Naah. No changes in it .

Comment: @AbhishekKulshrestha can you post your original image? Can you create in photoshop your desired result?

Comment: Added the image of the desired result.

Comment: @AbhishekKulshrestha an ImageView with height and width as match_parent and the scaleType as fitXY should do the work. If not, can you post your project in github?

Comment: It did not work. I can create a similar problem in another project and then post that on GitHub if you want.

Comment: There is not much to do, just use the same style and this layout. You will have the same problem.

Comment: You want me to post project with same problem on github?

Comment: @AbhishekKulshrestha I want you to post any code that I could reproduce the problem.

Comment: I uploaded the proect on this link. Please check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Y9-jpvsfOBMFJicTl1alBycHc/view?usp=sharing