# How to create a transparent statusbar

Tags: android, statusbar

Hi I am trying to create a transparent status bar for my latest project but I am not able to find a solution for my Api level 16. Can any one give me a solution to create a transparent status bar. [image: here is the sample]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar)

Answer (score 0):

set FLAG to your Java Class above OnCreate Method.
Add those Line.

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```